# How to loop through a plain JavaScript object with the objects as members

Tags: javascript, loops

How can I loop through all members in a JavaScript object, including values that are objects?

For example, how could I loop through this (accessing the "your_name" and "your_message" for each)?

```
var validation_messages = {
    "key_1": {
        "your_name": "jimmy",
        "your_msg": "hello world"
    },
    "key_2": {
        "your_name": "billy",
        "your_msg": "foo equals bar"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2254, accepted):

```
for (var key in validation_messages) {
    // skip loop if the property is from prototype
    if (!validation_messages.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;

    var obj = validation_messages[key];
    for (var prop in obj) {
        // skip loop if the property is from prototype
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) continue;

        // your code
        alert(prop + " = " + obj[prop]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Internet Explorer does not agree (*sigh*), says "Object does not support this property or method" when you do obj[prop]. I have yet to find a solution to this.

Comment: @MildFuzz actually it makes sense if you consider that JS objects do not necessary have numerical keys. You can't just iterate through an object. JS's `for in` is very similar to a traditional `foreach`.

Comment: for...in is a good solution, but if you use promises in the for()-loop be careful, because if you create a var in the loop, you can't use it in the promise' then-function. You var in the loop exists only one time, so it has in every then-function the same, even the last value. If you have that problem, try "Object.keys(obj).forEach" or my answer below.

Comment: hasOwnProperty is almost always redundant for modern browsers (IE9 +).

Comment: You are not supposed to use a var in a for loop. You need to use the let keyword.

Answer (score 917):

Under ECMAScript 5, you can combine `Object.keys()` and `Array.prototype.forEach()`:

```js
var obj = {
  first: "John",
  last: "Doe"
};

//
// Visit non-inherited enumerable keys
//
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {

  console.log(key, obj[key]);

});
```

Comment: +1 for brevity of code but apparently, doesn't perform as efficient as a for surprisingly. [JSPerf - for in vs Object.keys](http://jsperf.com/objdir)

Comment: Beware of this error using this approach: "TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object". The `for ... in ... hasOwnProperty` pattern can be called on anything, as far as I can tell (object, array, null, undefined, true, false, number primitive, objects).

Comment: @techiev2 those tests were never valid. See my updated ones for the current state of performance: http://jsperf.com/objdir/20

Comment: @techiev2: it's not `Object.keys()` which makes it slow, it's rather the `forEach()` and the repeated access to `.length`! If you use a classic `for`-loop instead, it's almost twice as fast as `for..in` + `hasOwnProperty()` in Firefox 33.

Comment: Does keys(obj) return property keys of the child objects too? to what depth? does it avoid possible loop references?

Comment: @SabaAhang No. The purpose of [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) is to get only the direct (vs inherited) keys of an object, as an array. This excludes keys set on the object's prototypes that it inherits. In other words, it only includes keys where [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) is true.

Comment: Object.keys(obj).reduce((p,c)=> p.concat(obj[c]),[])

Comment: seems like [this is now the only jslint recommended `for` loop](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30518734/274502). from the site's help: _" JSLint does not recommend use of the `for` statement. Use array methods like `forEach` instead. JSLint does not recommend use of the `for in` statement. Use `Object.keys` instead."_

Comment: @techiev2 that is not surprising at all, Axel Rauschmayer's method is using `keys` function and `forEach` function and it needs to parse the anonymous function and then it calls the anonymous function on each element of the forEach loop. If you know about programming you will understand all this parsing and function calls is taking much more time than a native solution like the for structure loop.

Comment: If you are in react, you probably want to use `.map()` instead of `.forEach()` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39965579/how-to-loop-an-object-in-react

Comment: A more functional and encapsulated alternative is 
`const mapr = o => Object.keys(o).map(key => o[key])`
then
`mapr(obj)`

Answer (score 451):

In **ES6/2015** you can loop through an object like this (using the [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)):

```js
Object.keys(myObj).forEach(key => {
  console.log(key);        // the name of the current key.
  console.log(myObj[key]); // the value of the current key.
});
```

[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/feribofaqa/edit?html,js,console,output)

In **ES7/2016** you can use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) instead of `Object.keys` and loop through an object like this:

```js
Object.entries(myObj).forEach(([key, val]) => {
  console.log(key); // the name of the current key.
  console.log(val); // the value of the current key.
});
```

The above would also work as a **one-liner**:

```js
Object.entries(myObj).forEach(([key, val]) => console.log(key, val));
```

[jsbin](https://jsbin.com/tokotusuze/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

In case you want to loop through nested objects as well, you can use a **recursive** function (ES6):

```js
const loopNestedObj = obj => {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    if (obj[key] && typeof obj[key] === "object") loopNestedObj(obj[key]); // recurse.
    else console.log(key, obj[key]); // or do something with key and val.
  });
};
```

[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/ruravuhelu/edit?html,js,console,output)

The same as function above, but with **ES7** `Object.entries()` instead of `Object.keys()`:

```js
const loopNestedObj = obj => {
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, val]) => {
    if (val && typeof val === "object") loopNestedObj(val); // recurse.
    else console.log(key, val); // or do something with key and val.
  });
};
```

Here we loop through nested objects change values and return a new object in one go using `Object.entries()` combined with [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) (**ES10/2019**):

```js
const loopNestedObj = obj =>
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj).map(([key, val]) => {
      if (val && typeof val === "object") [key, loopNestedObj(val)]; // recurse
      else [key, updateMyVal(val)]; // or do something with key and val.
    })
  );
```

Another way of looping through objects is by using  **for ... in** and **for ... of**. See [vdegenne's nicely written answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46386334/1612318).

Comment: for your ES7 using Object.entries example, you need to wrap the arrow function parameters [key,val] in parentheses like:  `Object.entries(myObj).forEach(([key, val]) => {  /* statements*/  }

Comment: I think it would be useful to add the fact that Object.entries and Object.keys does not iterate over the prototype which is the big difference between it and the for in construct.

Comment: You don't even need the array as the param, you can just do `Object.entries(obj).map(e=>{ let key = e[0]; let value = e[1];})`

Answer (score 397):

The problem with this

```
for (var key in validation_messages) {
   var obj = validation_messages[key];
   for (var prop in obj) {
      alert(prop + " = " + obj[prop]);
   }
}
```

is that you’ll also loop through the primitive object's prototype.

With this one you will avoid it:

```
for (var key in validation_messages) {
   if (validation_messages.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      var obj = validation_messages[key];
      for (var prop in obj) {
         if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            alert(prop + " = " + obj[prop]);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: In short: check [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) inside your `for`-`in` loops.

Comment: Note that this is only necessary if your object HAS prototype methods. For example, if the object you're looping through is just a JSON object, you won't need this check.

Comment: @rednaw To be safe I use that check because Object.prototype can be modified. No sane script would do that, but you cannot control what scripts might be run in your page by insane browser extensions. Browser extensions run in your page (on most browsers) and they can cause odd problems (e.g. set window.setTimeout to null!).

Answer (score 101):

Using [Underscore.js’s `_.each`](http://underscorejs.org/#each):

```
_.each(validation_messages, function(value, key){
    _.each(value, function(value, key){
        console.log(value);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, using underscore so definitely good to have a quick and clean option.

Answer (score 66):

> This answer is an aggregate of the solutions that were provided in this
> post with some [performance feedbacks](https://jsperf.com/es7-and-misc-loops). I think there is two
> use cases and the OP didn't mention if he needs to access the keys in order use them
> during the loop process.

### **I. The keys need to be accessed**

**✔ The `of` and `Object.keys` approach**

```
let k;
for (k of Object.keys(obj)) {

    /*        k : key
     *   obj[k] : value
     */
}
```

**✔ The `in` approach**

```
let k;
for (k in obj) {

    /*        k : key
     *   obj[k] : value
     */
}
```

*Use this one with caution, as it could print prototype'd properties of `obj`*

**✔ The ES7 approach**

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {

}
```

*However, at the time of the edit I wouldn't recommend the ES7 method, because JavaScript initializes a lot of variables internally to build this procedure (see the feedbacks for proof). Unless you are not developing a huge application which deserves optimization, then it is OK, but if optimization is your priority, you should think about it.*

### **II. We just need to access each value**

**✔ The `of` and `Object.values` approach**

```
let v;
for (v of Object.values(obj)) {

}
```

---

### More feedbacks about the tests:

- Caching `Object.keys` or `Object.values` performance is negligible

For instance,

```
const keys = Object.keys(obj);
let i;
for (i of keys) {
  //
}
// same as
for (i of Object.keys(obj)) {
  //
}
```

- For `Object.values` case, using a native `for` loop with cached variables in Firefox seems to be a little faster than using a `for...of` loop. However, the difference is not that important and Chrome is running `for...of` faster than native `for` loop, so I would recommend to use `for...of` when dealing with `Object.values` in any cases (4th and 6th tests).
- In Firefox, the `for...in` loop is really slow, so when we want to cache the key during the iteration it is better to use `Object.keys`. Plus Chrome is running both structure at equal speed (first and last tests).

You can check the tests here: https://jsperf.com/es7-and-misc-loops

Answer (score 60):

If you use recursion you can return object properties of any depth-

```
function lookdeep(object){
    var collection= [], index= 0, next, item;
    for(item in object){
        if(object.hasOwnProperty(item)){
            next= object[item];
            if(typeof next== 'object' && next!= null){
                collection[index++]= item +
                ':{ '+ lookdeep(next).join(', ')+'}';
            }
            else collection[index++]= [item+':'+String(next)];
        }
    }
    return collection;
}

//example

var O={
    a:1, b:2, c:{
        c1:3, c2:4, c3:{
            t:true, f:false
        }
    },
    d:11
};
var lookdeepSample= 'O={'+ lookdeep(O).join(',\n')+'}';


/*  returned value: (String)
O={
    a:1, 
    b:2, 
    c:{
        c1:3, c2:4, c3:{
            t:true, f:false
        }
    },
    d:11
}

*/
```

Comment: Beware of loops, like calling this on a DOM node.

Answer (score 34):

```
for(var k in validation_messages) {
    var o = validation_messages[k];
    do_something_with(o.your_name);
    do_something_else_with(o.your_msg);
}
```

Answer (score 33):

An optimized and improved version of AgileJon's answer:

```
var key, obj, prop, owns = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;

for (key in validation_messages ) {

    if (owns.call(validation_messages, key)) {

        obj = validation_messages[key];

        for (prop in obj ) {

            // Using obj.hasOwnProperty might cause you headache if there is
            // obj.hasOwnProperty = function(){return false;}
            // but 'owns' will always work
            if (owns.call(obj, prop)) {
                console.log(prop, "=", obj[prop]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you storing `hasOwnProperty` in `owns` and then calling `owns.call(obj, prop)` instead of just calling `obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)` as [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2869372/578288) does?

Comment: Because `obj` might have the `hasOwnProperty` function defined on it self so it will not use the one from `Object.prototype`. You can try before the `for` loop like this `obj.hasOwnProperty = function(){return false;}` and it will not iterate over any property.

Comment: @Azder +1 for the answer and +1 if I could for the nice thing about Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty. I saw that previously inside the source code of the underscore library but don't know why.

Answer (score 14):

p is the value

```
for (var key in p) {
  alert(key + ' => ' + p[key]);
}
```

OR

```
Object.keys(p).forEach(key => { console.log(key, p[key]) })
```

Answer (score 12):

In ES7 you can do:

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
  //
}
```

Comment: I made some tests, this method is really slow when dealing with large amount of data.

Comment: I use this almost all the time (2024). It may be slightly slower but for most code it doesn’t matter and the ergonomics are well worth it.

Answer (score 9):

```
for(var key in validation_messages){
    for(var subkey in validation_messages[key]){
        //code here
        //subkey being value, key being 'yourname' / 'yourmsg'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

A few ways to do that...

**1)** A two-layer for...in loop...

```
for (let key in validation_messages) {
   const vmKeys = validation_messages[key];
   for (let vmKey in vmKeys) {
      console.log(vmKey + vmKeys[vmKey]);
   }
}
```

**2)** Using `Object.key`

```
Object.keys(validation_messages).forEach(key => {
   const vmKeys = validation_messages[key];
   Object.keys(vmKeys).forEach(key => {
    console.log(vmKeys + vmKeys[key]);
   });
});
```

**3)** Recursive function

```
const recursiveObj = obj => {
  for(let key in obj){
    if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;

    if(typeof obj[key] !== 'object'){
      console.log(key + obj[key]);
    } else {
      recursiveObj(obj[key]);
    }
  }
}
```

And call it like:

```
recursiveObj(validation_messages);
```

Answer (score 8):

There are so many ways to traverse an object. Please have a look at below examples.

```
var obj = {'name':'John Doe','email':'johndoe@example.com'}
```

**Approach 1**

```
var keys = Object.keys(obj)
for(var i= 0; i < keys.length;i++){
  console.log(keys[i]+ ': ' + obj[keys[i]])
}
```

**Approach 2**

```
for(var key in obj){
  console.log(key+': '+ obj[key])
}
```

**Approach 3**

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
  console.log(key+ ': ' + obj[key])
})
```

Answer (score 6):

Another option:

```
var testObj = {test: true, test1: false};
for(let x of Object.keys(testObj)){
    console.log(x);
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution in Chrome 55.0 and you get a type error.  Your answer looks nice and succinct, if you can get it working it would probably be one of the better options.  I tried to figgure it out but don't understand your solution.

Answer (score 5):

Here comes the improved and recursive version of AgileJon's solution ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/94dj6cap/)):

```
function loopThrough(obj){
  for(var key in obj){
    // skip loop if the property is from prototype
    if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;

    if(typeof obj[key] !== 'object'){
      //your code
      console.log(key+" = "+obj[key]);
    } else {
      loopThrough(obj[key]);
    }
  }
}
loopThrough(validation_messages);
```

This solution works for all kinds of different depths.

Answer (score 5):

[ECMAScript 2017](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#8th_Edition_-_ECMAScript_2017), just finalized a month ago, introduces Object.values(). So now you can do this:

```
let v;
for (v of Object.values(validation_messages))
   console.log(v.your_name);   // jimmy billy
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var validation_messages = {
    "key_1": {
        "your_name": "jimmy",
        "your_msg": "hello world"
    },
    "key_2": {
        "your_name": "billy",
        "your_msg": "foo equals bar"
    }
}
for (var i in validation_messages) {
    console.log("i = \"" + i + "\"");
    console.log("validation_messages[\"" + i + "\"] = ");
    console.log(validation_messages[i]);
    console.log("\n");
    for (var j in validation_messages[i]) {
        console.log("j = \"" + j + "\"");
        console.log("validation_messages[\"" + i + "\"][\"" + j + "\"] = \"" + validation_messages[i][j] + "\"");
        console.log("\n");
    }
    console.log('\n');
}
```

Outputs:

```
i = "key_1"
validation_messages["key_1"] = 
{
  your_name:"jimmy",
  your_msg:"hello world"
}

j = "your_name"
validation_messages["key_1"]["your_name"] = "jimmy"

j = "your_msg"
validation_messages["key_1"]["your_msg"] = "hello world"


i = "key_2"
validation_messages["key_2"] = 
{
  your_name:"billy",
  your_msg:"foo equals bar"
}

j = "your_name"
validation_messages["key_2"]["your_name"] = "billy"

j = "your_msg"
validation_messages["key_2"]["your_msg"] = "foo equals bar"
```

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't get the previous answere to do quite what I was after.

After playing around with the other replies here, I made this. It's hacky, but it works!

For this object:

```
var myObj = {
    pageURL    : "BLAH",
    emailBox   : {model:"emailAddress", selector:"#emailAddress"},
    passwordBox: {model:"password"    , selector:"#password"}
};
```

... this code:

```
// Get every value in the object into a separate array item ...
function buildArray(p_MainObj, p_Name) {
    var variableList = [];
    var thisVar = "";
    var thisYes = false;
    for (var key in p_MainObj) {
       thisVar = p_Name + "." + key;
       thisYes = false;
       if (p_MainObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          var obj = p_MainObj[key];
          for (var prop in obj) {
            var myregex = /^[0-9]*$/;
            if (myregex.exec(prop) != prop) {
                thisYes = true;
                variableList.push({item:thisVar + "." + prop,value:obj[prop]});
            }
          }
          if ( ! thisYes )
            variableList.push({item:thisVar,value:obj});
       }
    }
    return variableList;
}

// Get the object items into a simple array ...
var objectItems = buildArray(myObj, "myObj");

// Now use them / test them etc... as you need to!
for (var x=0; x < objectItems.length; ++x) {
    console.log(objectItems[x].item + " = " + objectItems[x].value);
}
```

... produces this in the console:

```
myObj.pageURL = BLAH
myObj.emailBox.model = emailAddress
myObj.emailBox.selector = #emailAddress
myObj.passwordBox.model = password
myObj.passwordBox.selector = #password
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it's worth pointing out that jQuery sorts this out nicely with `$.each()`.

See: [**.each()**](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

**Example:**

```
$('.foo').each(function() {
    console.log($(this));
});
```

`$(this)` being the single item inside the object. Swap `$('.foo')` to a variable if you don't want to use jQuery's selector engine.

Answer (score 3):

```js
var obj = {
    name: "SanD",
    age: "27"
}
Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => console.log(key,obj[key]));
```

To loop through the JavaScript *Object* we can use forEach and to optimize the code we can use the arrow function.

Answer (score 3):

using [lodash _.forEach](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#forEach):

```js
_.forEach({ 'a': 1, 'b': 2 }, function(value, key) {
  console.log(key, value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

### In 2023+ you want immutable and universal functions

This walks through your multidimensional object composed of sub-objects, arrays and string and apply a custom function:

```
export const iterate = (object, func) => {
  const entries = Object.entries(object).map(([key, value]) =>
    Array.isArray(value)
      ? [key, value.map(e => iterate(e, func))]
      : typeof value === 'object'
      ? [key, iterate(value, func)]
      : [key, func(value)]
  );
  return Object.fromEntries(entries);
};
```

Usage:

```
const r = iterate(data, e=>'converted_'+e);
console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 1):

## forEach2

(Found [here](https://gomakethings.com/the-es6-way-to-loop-through-objects-with-vanilla-javascript/)):

```
var lunch = {
    sandwich: 'ham',
    age: 48,
};
lunch.forEach2(function (item, key) {
    console.log(key);
    console.log(item);
});
```

Code:

```
if (!Object.prototype.forEach2) {
    Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'forEach2', {
        value: function (callback, thisArg) {
            if (this == null) {
                throw new TypeError('Not an object');
            }
            thisArg = thisArg || window;
            for (var key in this) {
                if (this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    callback.call(thisArg, this[key], key, this);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution that works for me is the following:

```
_private.convertParams = function(params){
    var params = [];
    Object.keys(values).forEach(function(key) {
        params.push({"id":key, "option":"Igual", "value":params[key].id})
    });
    return params;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Exotic one - deep traverse

```
JSON.stringify(validation_messages,(field,value)=>{
  if(!field) return value;

  // ... your code

  return value;
})
```

In this solution we use [replacer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) which allows to deep traverse the whole object and nested objects - on each level you will get all fields and values. If you need to get the full **path** to each field, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61693085/860099).

```js
var validation_messages = {
    "key_1": {
        "your_name": "jimmy",
        "your_msg": "hello world"
    },
    "key_2": {
        "your_name": "billy",
        "your_msg": "foo equals bar",
        "deep": {
          "color": "red",
          "size": "10px"
        }
    }
}

JSON.stringify(validation_messages,(field,value)=>{
  if(!field) return value;

  console.log(`key: ${field.padEnd(11)} - value: ${value}`);

  return value;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ES8 Object.entries() should be a more compact way to achieve this.

```
Object.entries(validation_messages).map(([key,object]) => {

    alert(`Looping through key : ${key}`);

    Object.entries(object).map(([token, value]) => {
        alert(`${token} : ${value}`);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var validation_messages = {
    "key_1": {
        "your_name": "jimmy",
        "your_msg": "hello world"
    },
    "key_2": {
        "your_name": "billy",
        "your_msg": "foo equals bar"
    }
}

for ( const item in validation_messages ) {
    console.log( item )
    console.log( validation_messages[item]["your_name"] )   
    console.log( validation_messages[item]["your_msg"] )
    console.log( '---')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently tackled a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77651685/23020032) a few days back. I encourage readers to check it out to gain an understanding of the concepts discussed in this answer. Additionally, I've utilized data from that question.

```
import { ArrayQueue } from "@ut8pia/classifier/queue/ArrayQueue.js";
import { Path } from "@ut8pia/fluent/util/Path.js";
import assert from "assert";

const root = {
    name: 'root',
    children: [
        {name: 'Child 1',
        children: [
            { name: 'Child 1.1', children: [] },
            { name: 'Child 1.2', children: [
                { name: 'Child 1.2.1', children: [] },
                { name: 'Child 1.2.2', children: [] },
                { name: 'Child 1.2.3', children: [] }
            ]}
        ]},
        {name: 'Child 2', children: [
            { name: 'Child 2.1', children: [] },
            { name: 'Child 2.2', children: [] },
        ]},
        { name: 'Child 3', children: [] }
    ]},

    n = 11;
```

This time, however, we'll generate paths of properties as entries `[name, value]` instead of paths of objects in the tree. Since each object stores two inner properties
`{name: ..., children: ...}`
each object yields 3 properties: the outer property storing the object itself and the two inner ones. Consequently, we anticipate `n * 3` properties, which also equals the expected count of property paths.

```
const
    np = n * 3
```

Unlike before, where the children objects of each object within the tree were explicitly outlined by the `children` property, this time, defining the children of each property in the tree requires explicit specification.

```
const children = ([name, obj]) => !(obj instanceof Object)? []
    : typeof(obj) === 'function'? []
        : Array.isArray(obj)? obj.map((item, i) => [i, item])
            : Object.entries(obj);
```

Conceptually, however, the challenge of navigating through all the properties in the tree mirrors precisely the task of traversing all the objects within the tree. This correspondence becomes evident when examining the code.

```
const
    space = path => path.across(children(path.last)),
    search = new ArrayQueue()
        .let(Path.of([undefined, root]))
            .search(space)
```

You can validate the proposed solution by:

```
const 
    assert.equal(search.toArray().length, np)
```

Answer (score -7):

In my case (on the basis of the preceding) it is possible for any number of levels.

```
var myObj = {
    rrr: undefined,
    pageURL    : "BLAH",
    emailBox   : {model:"emailAddress", selector:"#emailAddress"},
    passwordBox: {model:"password"    , selector:"#password"},
    proba: {odin:{dva:"rr",trr:"tyuuu"}, od:{ff:5,ppa:{ooo:{lll:'lll'}},tyt:'12345'}}
};


function lookdeep(obj,p_Name,gg){
    var A=[], tem, wrem=[], dd=gg?wrem:A;
    for(var p in obj){
        var y1=gg?'':p_Name, y1=y1 + '.' + p;
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(p)){
           var tem=obj[p];
           if(tem && typeof tem=='object'){
               a1=arguments.callee(tem,p_Name,true);
               if(a1 && typeof a1=='object'){for(i in a1){dd.push(y1 + a1[i])};}
            }
            else{
               dd.push(y1 + ':' + String(tem));
            }
        }
    };
    return dd
};


var s=lookdeep(myObj,'myObj',false);
for (var x=0; x < s.length; ++x) {
console.log(s[x]+'\n');}
```

Result:

```
["myObj.rrr:undefined",
"myObj.pageURL:BLAH",
"myObj.emailBox.model:emailAddress",
"myObj.emailBox.selector:#emailAddress",
"myObj.passwordBox.model:password",
"myObj.passwordBox.selector:#password",
"myObj.proba.odin.dva:rr",
"myObj.proba.odin.trr:tyuuu",
"myObj.proba.od.ff:5",
"myObj.proba.od.ppa.ooo.lll:lll",
"myObj.proba.od.tyt:12345"]
```