# Check what holds in [object Object] in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a jQuery plugin which returns the object, for example using the below code.

```
onSuccess: function(data, status){
    alert(data);
}
```

**returns [object Object]**

as it is returning the object i would like to know how do i check all the contents that holds inside that object using js `alert();`

also i would like to know if JS object and JSON are one and the same.

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use proper debugging tools like Firebug for Firefox or the built in Chrome developer tools. Then you can inspect objects with `console.log` or `console.dir`.

`alert` is not meant for debugging. It can only output strings, which is of limited use as you already noticed.

---

> also i would like to know if JS object and JSON are one and the same.

No, they are not. [JSON](http://json.org/) is a *data exchange format*, similar to what XML can be used for, whereas a JavaScript object is a *data type* in JavaScript.

If you are wondering whether  JavaScript object literals are JSON, then this answer has to be answered with *no* as well.

These are object literals

```
var foo = {foo: "bar"};
var foo = {"foo": "bar"};
```

whereas JSON can only exist inside *strings* in JavaScript:

```
var foo = '{"foo": "bar"}';
```

and which then has to be *parsed* into a equivalent *JavaScript data type*. This is done by parsers such as the built-in [`JSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JSON) or [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).

Don't let their similar syntax/structure fool you.

Comment: i do use chrome developer tool console

Comment: got it, is there anyway i could peek what is inside the object?

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar: As I said, with `console.log` or `console.dir`.... you have to open the console then to have a look at the output.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of your question, check this: [How to Loop through plain JavaScript object with objects as members?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921789/how-to-loop-through-javascript-object-literal-with-objects-as-members)

And for your second question regarding json and js object: No, json is a string representation of a data structure, read here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON. However, it easy to parse a json to a js object.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [.data( key, value ) or .data( obj )](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

where
**key** - A string naming the piece of data to set.
**value** -The new data value; it can be any Javascript type including Array or Object.

**obj** - An object of key-value pairs of data to update.

**OR**
You can also use [jQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)