# How to get data from list

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch-2

Hi i am new to sencha touch 2. i am consuming web service. it is returning data in list oject.
so how to iterate the data from list

here is output:

```
request: Array[2]
0: Object
Address: "1 Bangalore"
Name: "Vinay"
__type: "Customer:#WcfService1"
__proto__: Object
1: Object
Address: "1 Kerala"
Name: "Sujay"
__type: "Customer:#WcfService1"
```

Comment: Have you tried `request[0]` yet?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921789/how-to-loop-through-javascript-object-literal-with-objects-as-members

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3010848/365188

Comment: ya..i tried request[0].Address. here i am able to take value..i need how put foreach loop for above code...please tel me how to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just iterate the results.

```
for (person in request) {
   doSomethingWithPerson(person);
}
```

your person would be just an object with the .Name and .Address properties.