# Each for object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have object in JavaScript:

```
var object = someobject;

Object { aaa=true, bbb=true, ccc=true }
```

How can I use each for this?

```
 object.each(function(index, value)) {
      console.log(value);
 }
```

Not working.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921789/how-to-loop-through-javascript-object-literal-with-objects-as-members

Comment: Are you using jQuery? What result do you expect? Three 'true' in console?

Comment: jQuery's documentation of $.each (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) has a perfect example -- see 2nd code block on the page. Uses alert() instead of console.log().

Answer (score 326, accepted):

A javascript Object does not have a standard .each function. jQuery provides a function. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/ The below should work

```
$.each(object, function(index, value) {
    console.log(value);
});
```

Another option would be to use vanilla Javascript using the `Object.keys()` and the Array `.map()` functions like this

```
Object.keys(object).map(function(objectKey, index) {
    var value = object[objectKey];
    console.log(value);
});
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

These are usually better than using a vanilla Javascript for-loop, unless you really understand the implications of using a normal for-loop and see use for it's specific characteristics like looping over the property chain.

But usually, a for-loop doesn't work better than `jQuery` or `Object.keys().map()`. I'll go into two potential issues with using a plain for-loop below.

---

Right, so also pointed out in other answers, a plain Javascript alternative would be

```
for(var index in object) { 
    var attr = object[index]; 
}
```

There are two potential issues with this:

1 . You want to check whether the attribute that you are finding is from the object itself and not from up the prototype chain. This can be checked with the `hasOwnProperty` function like so

```
for(var index in object) { 
   if (object.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
       var attr = object[index];
   }
}
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty for more information.

The `jQuery.each` and `Object.keys` functions take care of this automatically.

2 . Another potential issue with a plain for-loop is that of scope and non-closures. This is a bit complicated, but take for example the following code. We have a bunch of buttons with ids button0, button1, button2 etc, and we want to set an onclick on them and do a `console.log` like this:

```
<button id='button0'>click</button>
<button id='button1'>click</button>
<button id='button2'>click</button>

var messagesByButtonId = {"button0" : "clicked first!", "button1" : "clicked middle!", "button2" : "clicked last!"];
for(var buttonId in messagesByButtonId ) { 
   if (messagesByButtonId.hasOwnProperty(buttonId)) {
       $('#'+buttonId).click(function() {
           var message = messagesByButtonId[buttonId];
           console.log(message);
       });
   }
}
```

If, after some time, we click any of the buttons we will always get "clicked last!" in the console, and never "clicked first!" or "clicked middle!". Why? Because at the time that the onclick function is executed, it will display `messagesByButtonId[buttonId]` using the `buttonId` variable *at that moment*. And since the loop has finished at that moment, the `buttonId` variable will still be "button2" (the value it had during the last loop iteration), and so `messagesByButtonId[buttonId]` will be `messagesByButtonId["button2"]`, i.e. "clicked last!".

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures for more information on closures. Especially the last part of that page that covers our example.

Again, `jQuery.each` and `Object.keys().map()` solve this problem automatically for us, because it provides us with a `function(index, value)` (that has closure) so we are safe to use both index and value and rest assured that they have the value that we expect.

Comment: The "easier option" was not provided by you, just saying

Comment: True, I edited it in later on. Edited to make that clear.

Comment: "easier" isnt always the "best", so..

Comment: The for .. in statement is [deprecated](http://devdocs.io/javascript/statements/for_each...in)

Comment: @DanielSchmidt It is not deprecated. http://devdocs.io/javascript/statements/for...in You are referring to the "for each (... in ...)" which is different from "for (... in ...)"

Comment: Map is to create an array from another array (e.g : have a new array from another one with all values multiplied by 2 is `array1.map(x => x * 2)`). If one doesn't want to create a new array he can use forEach instead of map.

Answer (score 78):

```
for(var key in object) {
   console.log(object[key]);
}
```

Comment: thanks, but this return me "true", instead of aaa,bbb,ccc :(

Comment: yeah thats what its priting to console the value of attributes which is true for every key, if you want to see aaa, bbb, ccc then use `console.log(key);`

Comment: Note that you might want to check whether the found key comes from the object itself, or from up the prototype chain. Use object.hasOwnProperty(key) to check that

Comment: yes that's true, but adding property in object prototype is always a bad thing :) as that will affect all child object's like array, string etc

Comment: Thank you. It works for my objectives.

Comment: Would NOT recommend. for..in loops iterate over the entire prototype chain, which is virtually never what you want. Use Object.{keys,values,entries}, and iterate over the resulting array.

Answer (score -1):

```js
var object = { "a": 1, "b": 2};
$.each(object, function(key, value){
  console.log(key + ": " + object[key]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
//output
a: 1
b: 2
```

Comment: This is WRONG! $.each is JQuery-Framework!

Comment: this depends on jquery. Have a solution without jQuery?

Comment: you should add some title to your answer specifing it is jQuery dependant