# js - loop through multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm trying to implement jquery hotkeys in a for loop.

```
acKey = [
    ["keydown", "alt+d", open],
    ["keydown", "alt+a", close],
    ["keydown", "alt+s", max],
];
for(i=0;i<=acKey.length;i++)
{
    $(document).bind(acKey[i][0], acKey[i][1], acKey[i][2]);
}
```

However, it turned out error **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined**. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Your loop is `for(i=0;i<=acKey.length;i++)` (note the `i<=acKey.length`). What happens when `i==acKey.length`. Does `acKey[3]` exist?

Comment: So what should I do in this case?

Comment: Remove the `=`; it should be just `i<acKey.length`

Comment: Sometimes you do need "<=" in a for loop, but it's very much the exception. Any time you do use "<=", think about adding a comment to say why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is your index (out of bounds) when i=acKey.length.

You can use i<acKey.lenght or implement a "for each" iteration to avoid confusion:

```
acKey = [
    ["keydown", "alt+d", open],
    ["keydown", "alt+a", close],
    ["keydown", "alt+s", max],
];

var sub;
for(i in acKey) {
    sub = acKey[i];
    $(document).bind(sub[0], sub[1], sub[2]);
}
```

Comment: That's quite new to me. Thank you, cardeol.

Comment: `in` shouldn't be used to loop over arrays generally. See explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3010848/355499

Comment: In this case is completely safe.

Comment: Could you guys all point out this in several lines? Which cases are not safe?

Comment: I.E. If you use an object inherited properties are also enumerated. but in case of arrays shouldn't be any problem. I use a lot this structure. Even with objects. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11846484/each-for-object

Comment: Your method is really useful. Thanks for explanation, cardeol.

Comment: @cardeol It's safe as long as no one adds properties to Array (which I'd consider a big no no, but still). Consider: `Array.prototype.Muahahaha = "Gee will this show up everywhere I use 'in' to loop over an array? You bet ya!"; a = [1,2]; for(i in a) { console.log("i:" + i + ":" + a[i]);`. A bit contrived I know, but with javascript you just can't be sure  :)

Answer (score 4):

With due credit to @Matt who's comment points it out.

The commonest format for looping through an array is:

```
 for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
     doSomethingWith(array[i];
 }
```

Note that's a "less than" operator, not a "less than or equal to" operator.

This loop counts from 0 to `array.length - 1`, because the second part of the `for` statement: `i < array.length`, means "keep repeating for as long as i is less than array.length.

... and that's what you want, because arrays are numbered from 0 to length-1. That is, an array of length 4 is numbered 0,1,2,3.

If you loop while `i <= 4`, then the loop will execute for 0,1,2,3,4 -- and in Javascript, it will get `undefined` when it references `array[4]`.

Sometimes you do need "<=" in a for loop, but it's very much the exception. Any time you do use "<=", think about adding a comment to say why.