# How can we compare existing data of 2 objects of available keys only in js

Tags: javascript

I have 2 objects **a** and **b** i want to compare only data of objects of same keys

```
var a = {name1:'alisha',age:18,subject:{main:'javascript',major:'maths'}};
var b = {name1:'alisha',age:'18'};

 function compareData(a,b){
  return JSON.stringify(a) == JSON.stringify(b); 
 }

 console.log(compareData(a,b))
```

This is comparing all the keys but i want to compare only available data of available keys how can I do this

Comment: So you want the result to be true if all the keys/values of `b` are in `a`? Or if there's at least one? Or something else? Maybe an intersection of keys and then compare their values? Really hard to tell what you want.

Comment: Iterate over the properties of one object, check whether it is contained in the other object with `hasOwnProperty` or `in` and compare.

Comment: I want this to return return true because age and name properties have same data where properties might be not in proper order

Comment: Note that `JSON.stringify` is not the right tool for this, as it may order the keys differently than you expect.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11846484/each-for-object

Comment: So what if there are properties in `b` that do not exist in `a`? Is that a possibility? Should it be `false` in that case or should it only compare the intersection of matching property names?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this for shallow comparison:

```
// Returns true if the values are equal (shallow)
// for all properties that both objects have
function compareData(a,b){
  return Object.keys(a).filter( k => k in b ).every( k => a[k] === b[k] );
}
```

It will return false for your objects because one has a number for age and the other has a string. It will return true for these objects:

```
var a = {name1:'alisha',age:18,subject:{main:'javascript',major:'maths'}};
var b = {name1:'alisha',age:18};
```

Example:

```js
console.log( compareData( {}, {age: 5} ) ); // true (no shared properties)
console.log( compareData( {age: 5}, {age: 5} ) ); // true (equal shared properties)
console.log( compareData( {age: 4}, {age: 5} ) ); // false

var a = {name1:'alisha',age:18,subject:{main:'javascript',major:'maths'}};
var b = {name1:'alisha',age:18};

console.log( compareData( a, b ) ); // true

function compareData(a,b){
  return Object.keys(a).filter( k => k in b ).every( k => a[k] === b[k] );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looping through the first item keys and checking if:
  1. They exist
  2. The value is the same

Seems to work:

```js
var a = { name1:'alisha', age:18,subject:{main:'javascript',major:'maths'}};
var b = { name:'alisha', age: 19 };

function areTheSame(a,b){
  // fat arrow function returns true if any element has a difference
  return !Object.keys(a).some(key => {
    if(b.hasOwnProperty(key)){
      return a[key] !== b[key];
    }
    return false;
  });
}

console.log(areTheSame(a,b))
```