# Creating an array of appointments, sorted by date (MySQL/PHP)

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I am building a website where users can reserve appointments.

I am currently building a javascript app for the project, where user can pick a date from a calendar and see the available appointments. When I am building the calendar, I need to color dates by available appointments (ex. green if there's any).

In order to do that I need to iterate a javascript array that contains all available reservations. At the moment it looks something like this:

**[Object, Object, Object...]**

Where the object is a javascript object that contains appointment info. Here is the php service that serves the JSON:

```
<?php
require_once('../include/dbconnect.php');

$sql = "SELECT appointment.example,... 
person.example,... 
FROM appointment, person
WHERE appointment.reserved=0";

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

$array = array();
while($row = $stmt->fetchObject()){
array_push($array, $row);
}

echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

So this finally brings us to the question.

For easier javascript array scanning, I'd need an array/object includes appointments arranged/sorted by date. Then when I am creating an element that represents the date, I can check the object for matching data. Data like this:

```
{
15.09.2012 : Object,
16.09.2012 : Object{
    appointment1 : Object,
    appointment2 : Object
}
```

}

In the database an appointment has an attribute "date" which is currently a string like "16.09.2012". Should I also change it to unix timestamp?

How should I change the PHP service to output a JSON object that includes appointments filed under dates?

Comment: Why in your sql request, you don't add a `ORDER BY appointment.date_field` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to use associative arrays in php :

```
$assoc = array("key" => "value");
```

When you fetch your database records you can do something like this :

```
$array = array();
while($row = $stmt->fetchObject()){
$array[$row -> date] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($array);
```

For sorting, you can use the `ksort` ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php ) php function, to sort the array by key.

Now you will have a Javascript Object and not Javascript array.
Now you can iterate the object with for .. in javascript loop ( [How to Loop through plain JavaScript object with objects as members?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921789/how-to-loop-through-javascript-object-literal-with-objects-as-members) )

Comment: Thank you, this did exactly what I wanted. Great!

Comment: I noticed something. I added two appointments with the same date. The above loop only adds one appointment per day. I guess I have to add a if/else condition that makes a subarray if two or more appointments share the same date?

Comment: Well, you can just store in the following format :
appointment_date => array of appointments

And just check if the key exists - add to the array, else, create new array and insert the appointment

Answer (score 1):

You can give try as below:

```
$sql = "SELECT appointment.example,... 
person.example,... 
FROM appointment, person
WHERE appointment.reserved=0 ORDER BY appointment.date_field ASC";

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

$array = array();
while($row = $stmt->fetchObject()){
$array[$row->date_field][]=$row;
array_push($array, $row);
}

echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to construct an object consisting of date keys.  Instead:

1. include the dates in your current structure and sort the array by date:

   ```php
   <?php
   require_once('../include/dbconnect.php');

   $stmt = $db->query('
     SELECT   DATE(appointment.datetime) AS date,
              appointment.datetime,
              appointment.reserved,
              appointment.example,     -- do you really want to send sensitive
              person.example           -- data about appointments to the browser?
     FROM     appointment JOIN person ON ...
     WHERE    appointment.reserved = 0 -- should this be = 1?
     ORDER BY appointment.datetime
   ');

   echo json_encode($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ));
   ?>
   ```
2. then skip over matching days when progressing through the array:

   ```
   // loop over all dates displayed in calendar
   for (
     currentDate  = startDate, i = 0;
     currentDate <= endDate;
     currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1)
   ){

     // determine whether the current date is booked
     // and advance pointer to next date in array
     for (
       booked = false;
       i < arr.length && arr[i].date == currentDate;
       ++i
     ) booked |= arr[i].reserved;  // or just `booked = true` if query
                                   // returned only booked appointments

     // apply appropriate CSS to currentDate
     // ...
   }
   ```

You might even consider reducing the client-side overhead by first returning a JSON array only of booked dates (in which case the inner loop above could be replaced with a simple `if` statement):

```sql
SELECT   DISTINCT DATE(appointment.datetime) AS date
FROM     appointment JOIN person ON ...
WHERE    appointment.reserved = 0 -- should this be = 1?
ORDER BY date
```

And then, once the user selects a date, make a further query for the bookings on that date:

```sql
SELECT   appointment.datetime
FROM     appointment JOIN person ON ...
WHERE    appointment.reserved = 0 -- should this be = 1?
     AND DATE(appointment.datetime) = ?
ORDER BY appointment.datetime
```

Comment: I'd like to thank you for this, but I needed the appointments object because I am using it after user selects a day with free appointments (to list available appointments for that day). This is also why I am fetching only unreserved appointments. Your design may come in handy later on, in a different case.