# How to iterate over a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, loops, object, iteration, javascript-objects

I have an object in JavaScript:

```
{
    abc: '...',
    bca: '...',
    zzz: '...',
    xxx: '...',
    ccc: '...',
    // ...
}
```

I want to use a `for` loop to get its properties. And I want to iterate it in parts (not all object properties at once).

With a simple array I can do it with a standard `for` loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) { ... } // first part
for (i = 100; i < 300; i++) { ... } // second
for (i = 300; i < arr.length; i++) { ... } // last
```

But how to do it with objects?

Comment: Bear in mind that object properties are not stored in order. When you iterate over an object there is no guarantee to the order in which they will appear.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to loop through a plain JavaScript object with the objects as members?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921789/how-to-loop-through-a-plain-javascript-object-with-the-objects-as-members)

Comment: @JamesAllardice's comment is from 2013. Since 2015 objects now have a defined iteration order.

Comment: modern ECMAScript specification: array indices first in ascending order by value, then other string keys in ascending chronological order of property creation.

Answer (score 1279, accepted):

For iterating on keys of [Arrays, Strings, or Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69604222/343302), use `for .. in` :

```
for (let key in yourobject) {
  console.log(key, yourobject[key]);
}
```

With ES6, if you need both keys and values simultaneously, do

```
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(yourobject)) {
    console.log(key, value);
}
```

To avoid logging inherited properties, check with [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) :

```
for (let key in yourobject) {
   if (yourobject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      console.log(key, yourobject[key]);
   }
}
```

*You don't need to check `hasOwnProperty` when iterating on keys if you're using a simple object (for example one you made yourself with `{}`).*

[This MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) explains more generally how to deal with objects and their properties.

If you want to do it "in chunks", the best is to extract the keys in an array. As the order isn't guaranteed, this is the proper way. In modern browsers, you can use

```
let keys = Object.keys(yourobject);
```

To be more compatible, you'd better do this :

```
 let keys = [];
 for (let key in yourobject) {      
     if (yourobject.hasOwnProperty(key)) keys.push(key);
 }
```

Then you can iterate on your properties by index: `yourobject[keys[i]]` :

```
for (let i=300; i < keys.length && i < 600; i++) { 
   console.log(keys[i], yourobject[keys[i]]);
}
```

Comment: OP wants to perform this in chunks, not all keys in a single loop.

Comment: Yes. Not full object in one loop.

Comment: This does not answer the question on how to iterate through a part of the object.

Comment: @Cerbrus The OP allready knows how to iterate an array in parts. Using `keys` from the code given should be enough.

Comment: @Yoshi / @dystroy: `Object.keys()` support is IE 9+. For compatibility purposes, I'd suggest not using that.

Comment: @Cerbrus Please read before commenting ! What's not clear in *"To be more compatible, you'd better do this"* ?

Comment: +1 for the console.log() instead of alert() / and for providing the link to MDN

Comment: hi, sorry for bringing old topic, but is there any point of the `if (yourobject.hasOwnProperty(key))` ?, as i get the same result with only `keys.push(key)`, and it should be a little faster without the `if`

Comment: @am05mhz As I said, it's useless with most objects. But not for all. Try this: http://jsbin.com/hirivubuta/1/edit?js,console,output

Comment: 9 years developing in JS, and I always doubt myself with `for..of` and `for..in`, and ended up coming here.

Comment: @choz: I remember which method to use with the mnemonic "Javascript iteration is **foreign**" which sounds like "for . .in". I myself authored [a long post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69604222/343302) on the topic and still need the mnemonic.

Comment: Its recommended to avoid for...in, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript for details

Comment: @Adam - First off, that's a link to question which has 64 answers, not to any of the actual answers. Second off, that's about iterating over arrays, whereas this is about iterating over objects. Based on reading their warnings, I think `for ... in` is correct for objects.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare true. Also now I see that this is about iterating over the props of object or keys of an array.. Then `for ... in` is of course the right choice.

Answer (score 98):

Here is another iteration solution for modern browsers:

```
Object.keys(obj)
  .filter((k, i) => i >= 100 && i < 300)
  .forEach(k => console.log(obj[k]));
```

Or without the filter function:

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach((k, i) => {
    if (i >= 100 && i < 300) {
        console.log(obj[k]);
    }
});
```

However you must consider that properties in JavaScript object are not sorted, i.e. have no order.

Comment: If I will break loop, it will start from beginning of object next time, that is not right way.

Answer (score 50):

Using `Object.entries` you do something like this.

```
 // array like object with random key ordering
 const anObj = { 100: 'a', 2: 'b', 7: 'c' };
 console.log(Object.entries(anObj)); // [ ['2', 'b'],['7', 'c'],['100', 'a'] ]
```

The Object.entries() method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property [key, value]

So you can iterate over the Object and have `key` and `value` for each of the object and get something like this.

```
const anObj = { 100: 'a', 2: 'b', 7: 'c' };
Object.entries(anObj).map(obj => {
   const key   = obj[0];
   const value = obj[1];

   // do whatever you want with those values.
});
```

or like this

```
// Or, using array extras
Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  console.log(`${key} ${value}`); // "a 5", "b 7", "c 9"
});
```

For a reference have a look at the MDN docs for [Object Entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

Comment: Best answer on the page

Comment: Even if you're not a fan of "map", entries() is the best thing they've added in this century.

Answer (score 22):

With the new ES6/ES2015 features, you don't have to use an object anymore to iterate over a hash. You can use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). Javascript Maps keep keys in insertion order, meaning you can iterate over them without having to check the hasOwnProperty, which was always really a hack.

Iterate over a map:

```
var myMap = new Map();
myMap.set(0, "zero");
myMap.set(1, "one");
for (var [key, value] of myMap) {
  console.log(key + " = " + value);
}
// Will show 2 logs; first with "0 = zero" and second with "1 = one"

for (var key of myMap.keys()) {
  console.log(key);
}
// Will show 2 logs; first with "0" and second with "1"

for (var value of myMap.values()) {
  console.log(value);
}
// Will show 2 logs; first with "zero" and second with "one"

for (var [key, value] of myMap.entries()) {
  console.log(key + " = " + value);
}
// Will show 2 logs; first with "0 = zero" and second with "1 = one"
```

or use forEach:

```
myMap.forEach(function(value, key) {
  console.log(key + " = " + value);
}, myMap)
// Will show 2 logs; first with "0 = zero" and second with "1 = one"
```

Comment: forEach is the prefered one

Answer (score 19):

If you want the *key and value* when iterating, you can use a [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop with [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).

```
const myObj = {a: 1, b: 2}

for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(myObj)) {
    console.log(`key=${key} value=${value}`)
}

// output: 
// key=a value=1
// key=b value=2
```

Answer (score 8):

The only reliable way to do this would be to save your object data to 2 arrays, one of keys, and one for the data:

```
var keys = [];
var data = [];
for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        keys.push(key);
        data.push(obj[key]); // Not necessary, but cleaner, in my opinion. See the example below.
    }
}
```

You can then iterate over the arrays like you normally would:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    console.log(keys[i], data[i]);
    //or
    console.log(keys[i], obj[keys[i]]); // harder to read, I think.
}
for(var i = 100; i < 300; i++){
    console.log(keys[i], data[i]);
}
```

I am not using `Object.keys(obj)`, because that's IE 9+.

Answer (score 5):

*->if we iterate over a JavaScript object using and find key of array of 
  objects*

```
Object.keys(Array).forEach(key => {

 console.log('key',key)

})
```

Answer (score 4):

> If you have a simple object you can iterate through it using the following code:

```js
let myObj = {
  abc: '...',
  bca: '...',
  zzz: '...',
  xxx: '...',
  ccc: '...',
  // ...
};

let objKeys = Object.keys(myObj);

//Now we can use objKeys to iterate over myObj

for (item of objKeys) {
  //this will print out the keys
  console.log('key:', item);
  
  //this will print out the values 
  console.log('value:', myObj[item]);
}
```

> If you have a nested object you can iterate through it using the following code:

```js
let b = {
  one: {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3
  },
  two: {
    a: 4,
    b: 5,
    c: 6
  },
  three: {
    a: 7,
    b: 8,
    c: 9
  }
};

let myKeys = Object.keys(b);

for (item of myKeys) {
  //print the key
  console.log('Key', item)
  
  //print the value (which will be another object)
  console.log('Value', b[item])
  
  //print the nested value
  console.log('Nested value', b[item]['a'])
}
```

> If you have array of objects you can iterate through it using the following code:

```js
let c = [
{
  a: 1,
  b: 2
},
{
  a: 3,
  b: 4
}
];

for(item of c){
//print the whole object individually 
console.log('object', item);

//print the value inside the object
console.log('value', item['a']);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Define object in arguments and avoid selectors & subscripts**

There are a number of syntax choices but this one defines the object upfront in the closure's arguments which eliminates the need for selectors or subscripts in the iterator. `k` is key, `v` is value, `i` is index.

```
const obj = {
    kiwi: true,
    mango: false,
    pineapple: 500
};

Object.entries(obj).forEach(([k, v], i) => {
    console.log(k, v, i);
});

// kiwi true 0
// mango false 1
// pineapple 500 2
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to iterate the whole object at once you could use `for in` loop:

```
for (var i in obj) {
  ...
}
```

But if you want to divide the object into parts in fact you cannot. There's no guarantee that properties in the object are in any specified order. Therefore, I can think of two solutions.

First of them is to "remove" already read properties:

```
var i = 0;
for (var key in obj) {
    console.log(obj[key]);
    delete obj[key];
    if ( ++i > 300) break;
}
```

Another solution I can think of is to use Array of Arrays instead of the object:

```
var obj = [['key1', 'value1'], ['key2', 'value2']];
```

Then, standard `for` loop will work.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const o = {
  name: "Max",
  location: "London"
};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(o)) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}
```

**[Try online](https://code.labstack.com/BS36AIxC)**

Answer (score 1):

I finally came up with a handy utility function with a unified interface to iterate Objects, Strings, Arrays, TypedArrays, Maps, Sets, (any Iterables).

```
const iterate = require('@a-z/iterate-it');
const obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };

iterate(obj, (value, key) => console.log(key, value)); 
// a 1
// b 2
// c 3
```

https://github.com/alrik/iterate-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Really a PITA this is not part of standard Javascript.

```
/**
 * Iterates the keys and values of an object.  Object.keys is used to extract the keys.
 * @param object The object to iterate
 * @param fn (value,key)=>{}
 */
function objectForEach(object, fn) {
    Object.keys(object).forEach(key => {
        fn(object[key],key, object)
    })
}
```

Note: I switched the callback parameters to (value,key) and added a third object to make the API consistent other APIs.

Use it like this

```
const o = {a:1, b:true};
objectForEach(o, (value, key, obj)=>{
    // do something
});
```

Comment: upvoted just for your statement in the first sentence. Even though it'd be better if the value was first parameter, the index or key second parameter, and the object third parameter, to make it more like the array forEach(). I'd recommend recommending lodash though.

Comment: I do like the idea of the (value, key) order.  That is how a library such as Vue does it too.

Because the object is the context, it do think it belongs as the first parameter though.  That's pretty standard for functional programming.

Comment: I would agree here, were it not for ECMA-262 defining an array as an object having a forEach(), map(), reduce(), filter(), which all take callbacks receiving the order [value, index, array]. An object in JS can be understood as just another collection; and then these methods become unified in their parameters of [value, key|index, context] (this is what lodash and underscore are doing). In my opinion, this "unified collection" protocol is just stronger. Also, the object _isn't_ the context: you can set `this` to whatever you like for the callback, as the callback has its own context.

Comment: Perhaps I should have used the work receiver instead of this.  Anyway still a PITA; I would welcome the parameters in any order.

Comment: Oh, I see that we might have misunderstood each other. I was always commenting about the callback parameters and their order, not about the actual `objectForEach` function. Sorry if that was confusing.

Answer (score 1):

For object iteration we usually use a `for..in` loop. This structure will loop through all **enumerable** properties, including ones who are inherited via prototypal inheritance. For example:

```js
let obj = {
  prop1: '1',
  prop2: '2'
}

for(let el in obj) {
  console.log(el);
  console.log(obj[el]);
}
```

However, `for..in` will loop over all enumerable elements and this will not able us to split the iteration in chunks. To achieve this we can use the built in `Object.keys()` function to retrieve all the keys of an object in an array. We then can split up the iteration into multiple for loops and access the properties using the keys array. For example:

```js
let obj = {
  prop1: '1',
  prop2: '2',
  prop3: '3',
  prop4: '4',
};

const keys = Object.keys(obj);
console.log(keys);


for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  console.log(obj[keys[i]]);
}


for (let i = 2; i < 4; i++) {
  console.log(obj[keys[i]]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can loop through an object using for loop. Here is an example

```js
var myObj = {
    abc: 'ABC',
    bca: 'BCA',
    zzz: 'ZZZ',
    xxx: 'XXX',
    ccc: 'CCC',
}

var k = Object.keys (myObj);
for (var i = 0; i < k.length; i++) {
    console.log (k[i] + ": " + myObj[k[i]]);
}
```

**NOTE:** the example mentioned above will only work in IE9+. See Objec.keys browser support [here](https://caniuse.com/#search=object.keys).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Hand Made Solution:

```
function iterationForObject() {
    let base = 0,
        Keys= Object.keys(this);
    return {
        next: () => {
            return {
                value: {
                    "key": Keys[base],
                    "value": this[Keys[base]]
                },
                done: !(base++ < Keys.length)
            };
        }
    };
}
Object.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = iterationForObject;
```

And Then You Can Loop Any Object:

```
for ( let keyAndValuePair of (Object Here) ) {
    console.log(`${keyAndValuePair.key} => ${keyAndValuePair.value}`);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// method 1
var images = {};
images['name'] = {};
images['family'] = {};
images[1] = {};
images['name'][5] = "Mehdi";
images['family'][8] = "Mohammadpour";
images['family']['ok'] = 123456;
images[1][22] = 2602;
images[1][22] = 2602;
images[1][22] = 2602;
images[1][22] = 2602;
images[1][23] = 2602;

for (const [key1, value1] of Object.entries(images)){
    for (const [key2, value2] of Object.entries(value1)){
        console.log(`${key1} => ${key2}: ${value2}`);
    }
}


console.log("=============================");

// method 2
var arr = [];
for(var x = 0; x < 5; x++){
     arr[x] = [];    
     for(var y = 0; y < 5; y++){ 
         arr[x][y] = x*y;    
     }    
 }

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var cube = arr[i];
    for(var j = 0; j < cube.length; j++) {
        console.log("cube[" + i + "][" + j + "] = " + cube[j]);
    }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var Dictionary = {
  If: {
    you: {
      can: '',
      make: ''
    },
    sense: ''
  },
  of: {
    the: {
      sentence: {
        it: '',
        worked: ''
      }
    }
  }
};

function Iterate(obj) {
  for (prop in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) && isNaN(prop)) {
      console.log(prop + ': ' + obj[prop]);
      Iterate(obj[prop]);
    }
  }
}
Iterate(Dictionary);
```

Comment: Actually no. This implies that `Object`s are in-order. They're not. `If you can make sense of the sentence it worked` only works because of implementation details. It's not guaranteed to work at all.

Also you shouldn't TitleCase your functions & variables. That's for `class`es.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [lodash- A modern JavaScript utility library delivering modularity, performance & extras](https://lodash.com/) js to fast object iterate:-

```js
var  users  =   {
    'fred':     { 
        'user':   'fred',
            'age':  40 
    },
    'pebbles':  { 
        'user':   'pebbles',
         'age':  1 
    }
}; 
_.mapValues(users,  function(o)  { 
    return  o.age; 
});
// => { 'fred': 40, 'pebbles': 1 } (iteration order is not guaranteed)
// The `_.property` iteratee shorthand.
console.log(_.mapValues(users,  'age')); // returns age property & value 
console.log(_.mapValues(users,  'user')); // returns user property & value 
console.log(_.mapValues(users)); // returns all objects 
// => { 'fred': 40, 'pebbles': 1 } (iteration order is not guaranteed)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash-compat/3.10.2/lodash.js"></script>
```