# Ajax JSON Array - accessing the information

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays, json

I have the following code:

```
$.getJSON('../_javascripts/array.php')
    .success(function(response) { console.info(response); alert("success"); })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, status, error){ console.info(error); alert("error"); });
```

Which displays output within the console, however, I am trying to access that information (which is displayed within the console - it's an array) and can't seem able to.

**console output**

```
Object {P5yTZ947: Array[3], 11y6tdo8: Array[3], 66j8ttk2: Array[3], 27c7uqv0: Array[3], 44f6hvt7: Array[3]…}
```

I have tried the following:

```
alert(response);
alert(response[0]);
var array = response;
```

All of which bring back `undefined`.

Clearly I am doing something wrong but can't quite fathom what.  Any advice, feedback and comments welcomed.

Comment: Can you show us what it displays in the console?

Comment: where do you try these alert statements?

Comment: Instead of `console.info(response)` write `functionThatNeedsTheData(response)` and process/access it inside the function.

Comment: Have you tried console.log and then just playing around with it in the console?

Comment: Updated with console output.  I have tried using those options within and outside the $.getJSON.

Comment: @Zhouster - yes, stored as global variable and then tried the above statements again and no joy.  Either get [object[object] or undefined.

Comment: Well, `response` is clearly an object, so `response[0]` will definitely return `undefined`. And since `response` doesn't exist outside of the `success` callback, you can't access it there.

Comment: If you are using Chrome, you can browse into the contents of your JSON data. To do that, open the Dev Tools then refresh your page. After that, Go to Network, click on the JSON request on the left then click on the Preview sub tab.

Comment: @SiZiOUS - I can see it in the preview - am I missing something really obvious?  Why can't I get access to the data?

Comment: you have to access the reponse inside success function, where are you accessing it?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad - cheers, I have tried this but no joy, for example `.success(function(response) { console.info(response); alert("success"); alert(response);})`

Comment: what you in alert?? is alert coming?

Comment: what if you do this way: ``$.getJSON('../_javascripts/array.php',function(response){ alert(response) });``

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I get [Object Object]

Comment: then just iterate over it and get your results

Comment: @Homer_J Check this out: http://i.stack.imgur.com/YVQql.png

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I take it this has to be done within 'success' - is it then possible to access them outside of this?

Comment: @SiZiOUS - I have a similar output within the console but what I am struggling with is to access then later in my script.

Comment: you have to access it inside success function make a function and call in success like: ``myfunction(response);``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to answer you as we don't have any access to your `array.php` file. Try to debug the `response` output with the following code (you need to have the **Developer Console** opened):

```
$.getJSON('../_javascripts/array.php', function( data ) {
    $.each( data, function( key, value ) {
        console.log( key );
        for( var i in value ) {
            console.log( "  " + JSON.stringify(value[i]) );
        }
    });
});
```

Try to use breakpoints within **Google Chrome** console to inspect the `data` (Ajax response) variable contents.

Answer (score 0):

From what the console outputs it looks like what array.php is returning is an object with arrays in it.

Comment: Might be the case - any idea why?

Comment: If you had an associative array or an STD object in php then called json_encode() then it would most likly create what you see there

Answer (score 0):

Your handling of the response must be from within the callback functions given to `$.getJSON();`

That is, the scope of the response object in the case of success is only within the success function.  Put your success handling code in there (or call it from there) and you should be good to go.

For example:

```
function doSomethingWithSuccessResponse( response ){
  console.log( response );

  // Execute the rest of your success case logic here
}

$.getJSON('../_javascripts/array.php')
    .success(function(response) { doSomethingWithSuccessResponse(response); })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, status, error){ console.info(error); alert("error"); });
```

Or, more concisely:

```
function doSomethingWithSuccessResponse( response ){
  console.log( response );

  // Execute the rest of your success case logic here
}

$.getJSON('../_javascripts/array.php')
    .success(doSomethingWithSuccessResponse)
    .fail(function(jqXHR, status, error){ console.info(error); alert("error"); });
```

Similarly for the failure case - execute your failure handling logic within the failure callback.

It looks like your API is returning an object with embedded arrays:

```
Object {
  P5yTZ947: Array[3], 
  11y6tdo8: Array[3], 
  66j8ttk2: Array[3], 
  27c7uqv0: Array[3], 
  44f6hvt7: Array[3]…
}
```

Use [object-looping semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14379304/13264) to iterate through the object. Then use an inner loop to loop over the elements of the array:

```
for (var key in response) {
   if (response.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      // key is now "P5yTZ947" or "11y6tdo8", etc
      var innerArray = response[key];

      // Loop over the values of the inner array
      for( var i = 0; i < innerArray.length; i++ ){
        console.log( innerArray[i] );  // 
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Would that enable me to iterate through the array?

Comment: It should, yes. It looks like your API is returning an object (or dictionary/hash if thats more familiar to you). Iterating through the properties of a hash is a bit different in Javascript than iterating through an array.

Comment: For an object, iterate like this:

`for (var key in response) {
   if (response.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      console.log(key, response[key]);
   }
}`
http://stackoverflow.com/a/14379304/13264

Comment: @Homer_J added looping logic to the answer with a bit more explanation.