# Parse nested json in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

This is my json response in javascript.

```
{"1": {"11": "51","12": "52","13": "53","14": "54","15": "55"},"2": {"11": "51","12": "52","13": "53","14":"54","15": "55"},"4": {"11": "51","12": "52","13": "53","14": "54","15": "55"}}
```

I am parsing this json but it is not giving proper output.

```
for(var i=0; i<Object.keys(obj).length; i++)
{
  // here how should i parse the json and get all the key and values into the array.
}
```

Thanks

Comment: it's not clear what you're asking here.. what array are you talking about? also, the `json response` you gave is already parsed, and if you want to iterate that then check these out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379274/javascript-iterate-object and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties in the future be sure to be more specific in your questions

Comment: Yes, i want to iterate this response and add into a array.

Comment: Then the two question links from my last comment should help you out

Answer (score 0):

There's a native way of parsing JSON in Javascript which is [`JSON.parse(yourString)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FJSON%2Fparse).

Were you not aware of it or are you trying to create your own parser?