# jQuery retrieve JSON data error

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

First of all I want to tell you that I searched and didnot get any solution from stackoverflow's previous post for my problem.So I post my question here.

Following is data returned after `echo json_encode($flterarr);`
`{"2":{"surname":"Winchester","mobile":"07898989898","license":"1234567890b"},"3":{"surname":"winchester","mobile":"07898989891","license":"1234567890bytfty"},"4":{"surname":"Test","mobile":"07678543210","license":"23frd"}}`

Following is my ajax code

```
$.ajax(

    { 

        type:"POST",                                    

        url: '../icabz/filterRefresh.php',   

        data:  "filter_reset_surname="+filter_reset_surname+"&filter_reset_mobile="+filter_reset_mobile+"&filter_reset_reg_num="+filter_reset_reg_num+"&filter_reset_approval_status="+filter_reset_approval_status+"&filter_reset_logged_status="+filter_reset_logged_status,
        success: function(data)

        {
            alert(data);
            $.each( data, function(key,val) {

            alert(val);
                /*$.each( val, function( key1, val1 ) {

                alert(val1.surname);
                });*/
            });
        }

    });
```

when I alert the raw data (without using `dataType:"json" or $.parseJSON(data)`)returned from php page it is showing the data.But when I alert the returned data in the `$.each()` function it is showing the word and showing following in the console.

```
TypeError: invalid 'in' operand obj
typeof length === "number" && length > 0 && ( length - 1 ) in obj;
```

Now if I trying to use `dataType:"json" or $.parseJSON(data)` and alert the data.then it is showing [object Object].
I am using jQuery 1.11.1 version.

How can I fetch the data to get the surname?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use `dataType:"json"`
now, try to alert `data["2"].surname`, you should get "Winchester".
if you want to iterate over your object you can do it like:

```
for (var key in data) { console.log(key, data[key]); }
```

[taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379274/javascript-iterate-object)

```
for (var key in data) {
   for (var skey in data[key]) {
        console.log(skey);
   }
}
```

Comment: `for (var key in data) { console.log(key, data[key]); }`
I used this and it is showing the key.but I want the value.How can can I get the value as it is multidimensional data returned from JSON.

Comment: Just add another innear for loop (with different var names of course!)

Comment: for (var subkey in data[key]) { console.log(subkey)  }

Answer (score 0):

Use `dataType : "json"`

then, try below in your success part:

```
data= JSON.parse(data);

jQuery.each(data, function(key,val){
    alert(val.surname);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sachint/pryotLxj/

Comment: While I am trying to use your code it is the following error on console :

Comment: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data
 

json = JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: `success: function(data)

  {
   for (var key in data) 
   { 
    alert(data[key].surname);
}
}`