# jQuery each loop 3-Dimensional Object Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have a multidimensional array that I am trying to loop through. I want the loop to eventually look through the first object (in the example code it is: `"pressure"`), then perform a specific action for each object inside the first object.

But I can't even get it to work properly. I know my `$.each` function is completely wrong — I just can't figure out how to make it right. Of course I get nothing in the console.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var units = {
    "pressure": [
      {
        short: "atm",
        val: "1",
        long: "Atmosphere (standard)"
      }, {
        short: "bar",
        val: "1.01325027383089",
        long: "Bar"
      }, {
        short: "cmHg",
        val: "76.0000526890144",
        long: "Centimeter of Mercury (0&#8451;)"
      }, {
        short: "cmH2O",
        val: "1033.25183423631",
        long: "Centimeter of Water (4&#8451;)"
      }, {
        short: "ft-H2O",
        val: "33.899503811341",
        long: "Foot of Water (4&#8451;)"
      }, {
        short: "GPa",
        val: "0.00010132502738",
        long: "Gigapascal"
      }, {
        short: "HPa",
        val: "1013.25027383088",
        long: "Hectopascal"
      }, {
        short: "inHg",
        val: "29.9212805862261",
        long: "Inch of Mercury (0&#8451;)"
      }, {
        short: "inH2O",
        val: "406.793640435982",
        long: "Inch of Water (4&#8451;)"
      }, {
        short: "kPa",
        val: "101.325027383089",
        long: "Kilopascal"
      }, {
        short: "MPa",
        val: "0.10132502738309",
        long: "MegaPascal"
      }, {
        short: "mbar",
        val: "1013.25027383088",
        long: "Millibar"
      }, {
        short: "mtorr",
        val: "760000.526890144",
        long: "Millitorr"
      }, {
        short: "mmHg",
        val: "760.000205385833",
        long: "Millimeter of Mercury (0&#8451;)"
      }, {
        short: "mmH2O",
        val: "10332.5183423631",
        long: "Millimeter of Water (4&#8451;)"
      }, {
        short: "Pa",
        val: "101325.027383088",
        long: "Pascal"
      }, {
        short: "psf",
        val: "2116.21372690676",
        long: "Pound-Force/Square-Foot"
      }, {
        short: "psi",
        val: "14.6959793215884",
        long: "Pound-Force/Square-Inch"
      }, {
        short: "Torr",
        val: "760.000526890144",
        long: "Torr"
      }
    ],

    "density": [

      {
        short: "lb/in3",
        val: "1",
        long: "Pound / Inch-Cubed"
      }, {
        short: "lb/ft3",
        val: "1728.00001173627",
        long: "Pound / Foot-Cubed"
      }, {
        short: "slug/ft3",
        val: "53.707964051111",
        long: "Slug / Foot-Cubed"
      }, {
        short: "grain/ft3",
        val: "12094392.8271733",
        long: "Grain / Foot-Cubed"
      }, {
        short: "grain/in3",
        val: "6999.99988928036",
        long: "Grain / Inch-Cubed"
      }, {
        short: "g/cm3",
        val: "27.679904710267",
        long: "Gram / Centimeter-Cubed"
      }, {
        short: "g/cup",
        val: "6.548788655679",
        long: "Gram / Cup"
      }, {
        short: "g/L",
        val: "27679.9047102671",
        long: "Gram / Liter"
      }, {
        short: "kg/cm3",
        val: "0.02767990471",
        long: "Kilogram / Centimeter-Cubed"
      }, {
        short: "kg/L",
        val: "27.679904710267",
        long: "Kilogram / Liter"
      }, {
        short: "kg/m3",
        val: "27679.9047102671",
        long: "Kilogram / Meter-Cubed"
      }
    ]
  };

  $.each(units, function(index, obj) {
    $.each(obj, function(short, val) {
      console.log(obj.index.short);
      console.log(obj.index.val);
    });
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: In your case you might want to iterate with some for(var type in units){ for(var property in units[type]){ } }

Comment: `obj.index`? Don’t you mean `obj[index]`?

Comment: Just use plain javascript for..in..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript iterate object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379274/javascript-iterate-object)

Comment: @ShaunakD: jQuery's `$.each` works for both objects and arrays.

Comment: @RocketHazmat, my bad. Not sure why I said that. having used it many times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the `.` syntax to refer to object properties, you are trying to access that *literal* property.

For example, `obj.index.short`.  This looks for a property called `index` and then one called `short`.  I assume you want the `index` *variable* to be used, so that you are accessing the correct property.

Something like: `obj[index].short`.  This won't work either though, since your `obj[index]` value is an array.

What you want to do is loop over the outer object, then loop over each property (which is an array) and get the values of each array element (object).

Try this:

```
$.each(units, function(index, obj){
    // `index` is either "pressure" or "density"
    // `obj` is the value of that property (an array)
    $.each(obj, function(short, val){
        // `short` is the index in the array
        // `val` is each element in the array, it's an object
        console.log(val.short);
        console.log(val.val);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! this works great. I guess I shouldn't use "val" as a key

Comment: @Sanya: I guess so you don't have `val.val` which may look silly.  You can leave `val` as a property in your object and just change the code to use something else, like `data.val` or something.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to do something like this:

```
Object.keys(units).forEach((key, index) => { // loop over the units keys
    units[key].forEach(object => { // loop over the objects in arrays
        // do your stuff with the objects
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$.each(units, function(index, obj) {
console.log(index)
  $.each(obj, function(short, val ) {
    console.log(val.short);
    console.log(val.val);
  });
});
```

Comment: You were so close. Rocket Hazmat was just 1 minute quicker.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var units = {
    "pressure": [
      {
        short: "atm",
        val: "1",
        long: "Atmosphere (standard)"
      }, {
        short: "bar",
        val: "1.01325027383089",
        long: "Bar"
      }, {
        short: "cmHg",
        val: "76.0000526890144",
        long: "Centimeter of Mercury (0&#8451;)"
      }, {
        short: "cmH2O",
        val: "1033.25183423631",
        long: "Centimeter of Water (4&#8451;)"
      }, {
        short: "ft-H2O",
        val: "33.899503811341",
        long: "Foot of Water (4&#8451;)"
      }, {
        short: "GPa",
        val: "0.00010132502738",
        long: "Gigapascal"
      }, {
        short: "HPa",
        val: "1013.25027383088",
        long: "Hectopascal"
      }, {
        short: "inHg",
        val: "29.9212805862261",
        long: "Inch of Mercury (0&#8451;)"
      }, {
        short: "inH2O",
        val: "406.793640435982",
        long: "Inch of Water (4&#8451;)"
      }, {
        short: "kPa",
        val: "101.325027383089",
        long: "Kilopascal"
      }, {
        short: "MPa",
        val: "0.10132502738309",
        long: "MegaPascal"
      }, {
        short: "mbar",
        val: "1013.25027383088",
        long: "Millibar"
      }, {
        short: "mtorr",
        val: "760000.526890144",
        long: "Millitorr"
      }, {
        short: "mmHg",
        val: "760.000205385833",
        long: "Millimeter of Mercury (0&#8451;)"
      }, {
        short: "mmH2O",
        val: "10332.5183423631",
        long: "Millimeter of Water (4&#8451;)"
      }, {
        short: "Pa",
        val: "101325.027383088",
        long: "Pascal"
      }, {
        short: "psf",
        val: "2116.21372690676",
        long: "Pound-Force/Square-Foot"
      }, {
        short: "psi",
        val: "14.6959793215884",
        long: "Pound-Force/Square-Inch"
      }, {
        short: "Torr",
        val: "760.000526890144",
        long: "Torr"
      }
    ],

    "density": [

      {
        short: "lb/in3",
        val: "1",
        long: "Pound / Inch-Cubed"
      }, {
        short: "lb/ft3",
        val: "1728.00001173627",
        long: "Pound / Foot-Cubed"
      }, {
        short: "slug/ft3",
        val: "53.707964051111",
        long: "Slug / Foot-Cubed"
      }, {
        short: "grain/ft3",
        val: "12094392.8271733",
        long: "Grain / Foot-Cubed"
      }, {
        short: "grain/in3",
        val: "6999.99988928036",
        long: "Grain / Inch-Cubed"
      }, {
        short: "g/cm3",
        val: "27.679904710267",
        long: "Gram / Centimeter-Cubed"
      }, {
        short: "g/cup",
        val: "6.548788655679",
        long: "Gram / Cup"
      }, {
        short: "g/L",
        val: "27679.9047102671",
        long: "Gram / Liter"
      }, {
        short: "kg/cm3",
        val: "0.02767990471",
        long: "Kilogram / Centimeter-Cubed"
      }, {
        short: "kg/L",
        val: "27.679904710267",
        long: "Kilogram / Liter"
      }, {
        short: "kg/m3",
        val: "27679.9047102671",
        long: "Kilogram / Meter-Cubed"
      }
    ]
  };

  $.each(units, function(i, obj) {     
      console.log(i);
     $.each(obj, function(j, obj2) {
         console.log(obj2.short +' : '+obj2.val+' , '+obj2.long);
     });
    
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

units is an Object and pressure is a key to this object

```
var _getPressure=units.pressure // will return value of key pressure
 _getPressure.forEach(function(item){ // use Array forEach to loop through array
 document.write('<pre>'+item.short+'--'+item.val+'</pre>')
 })
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/41dc9ajc/)