# Javascript forEach - how to loop an object?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach

How can I use forEach to loop an object?

For instance:

```
var dataset = {
    "data" : {
        "particles" : {},
        "no2" : {},
        "timestamp" : {}
    }
};
```

js:

```
dataset.data.forEach(function(field, index) {
    console.log(field);
});
```

error:

> Uncaught TypeError: dataset.data.forEach is not a function

Any ideas?

Comment: `forEach` is a `method` of `array`, not of `object`..Use `for-in` loop of `Object.keys(OBJECT).forEach`

Comment: and also - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object

Comment: This has been answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379274/javascript-iterate-object

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use a `for` loop instead.`for of` or `for in` are good candidates `.forEach` is not going to work here...

```js
const dataset = {
    "data" : {
        "particles" : {},
        "no2" : {},
        "timestamp" : {}
    }
};

// for in
for (const record in dataset.data) {
  if (dataset.data[record]) {
    console.log(record);
  }
}

// for of
for (const record of Object.keys(dataset.data)) {
  if (record) {
    console.log(record);
  }
}
```

You may have to do some additional work or provide a better explanation on what you're trying to solve if you want something more specific.