# Javascript object forEach howto?

Tags: javascript

In the following JavaScript code,

```
obj = {};

// This work as intented
obj['a'] = { item1: 'a1', item2: 'a2' };
console.log(obj);

// Object.keys() works too
console.log(Object.keys(obj));

// forEach does not, why? and how to fix?
console.log('forEach');
obj.forEach(o => console.log(o));
```

What is needed to have forEach working?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379274/javascript-iterate-object.

Comment: @torazaburo This is not a duplicate. I know the for-loop method, but I want to use forEach, which I thought I could.

Comment: You can't, because `forEach` does not exist on objects. The duplicate question goes into great detail on how to loop across object properties, including `forEach` across object keys, `for...in`, and newer ES6 approaches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have here is a JavaScript question, not a TypeScript question. TS and JS have the same runtime semantics.

`forEach` is a method of `Array`. Objects don't have `forEach`. The semantics of `forEach` don't make sense on regular objects -- your `obj` doesn't have a `length` or a `0` property, for example, which are the kinds of things `forEach` looks for.

Comment: You are correct. Somehow I got the misconception that I should able to use it that way and has been bugging me for awhile.