# How to find the length of an object and select them with index?

Tags: javascript, arrays

The backend gave me a strange websocket to work with where the array data of `[2,4,5,1,3,5,...]` has been processed as `{'00:00':{...'count':2...}...}`...

So first I need to count the length of an object, and when I use object.length, it returns `undefined`...

And then I need to recreate an array by using:

```
var newArray = [];
for(var i = 0; i < object.length; i++){
  newArray.push(object[i].count);
}
```

My question is how to find the length of an array with names and keys and select them with index?

It looks like I have to first get an array from an object with `Object.keys` or `Object.values` and then work from there.

Comment: Don't really get the question, but is something like [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) what you're after?

Comment: what does console.log(array) say?

Comment: Its not an array its an object, the way to know its length is to walk it: [Javascript iterate object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379274/javascript-iterate-object)

Comment: Okay guys let me give it a try. Sorry I will fix the terminology in a moment.

Comment: If you would like to use a `for` loop then it should be like in the form of `for (var key in obj) doSomethingWith(obj[key]);`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I have to first get an array from an object with `Object.keys` or `Object.values` and then work from there.