# Javascript Object Array loop not interrating

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have a problem with a `for` loop. What the problem is I have a `for` that is going through an object and it is only going through the array once. How can I loop through the entire object array loop? The current code is below:

```
var i = 0;
for (var key in data) {
  console.log(data[key].allProducts[i]);
  i++;
}
```

Comment: Add an inner loop off of the inner array.  Also, if there **is** only a single property on the `data`, there's really no point in the outer loop.

Comment: Well without seeing the JSON @Talpar is right, more than likely you need an inner loop to actually traverse the inner data. Can you add the JSON?

Comment: What is `data`?

Comment: If you could show us the structure and point out what it is you're trying to loop over we can help. `data` seems to be an object and you're looping over the `keys` (`data[key]`) - but are you asking how you can loop over the values that are stored  if `data[key]` is an array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to iterate over a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379274/how-to-iterate-over-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You only have one loop trying to control two variables, which isn't what you're trying to do. Assuming data keys are something like `['a', 'b', 'c']`, you're *actually* getting data['a'][1], data['b'][2], data['c'][3].

What you need is two nested loops:

```
for (var key in data) {
    var productsLength = data[key].allProducts.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < productsLength; i++) {
        console.log(data[key].allProducts[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: That did it. I was trying to find way to avoid doing an inner loop. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you are use the indexes here, why not at once use a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop instead? Then you don't have any need accessing the properties itself

Depending on your `data` object, you might need to use [`Object.values( data )`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) or stick with your previous [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop, but I guess the principle is clear :)

```js
const data = {
 group1: {
  allProducts: [
    { id: 1, name: 'product 1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'product 2' },
    { id: 3, name: 'product 3' },
    { id: 4, name: 'product 4' }
  ]
 },
 group2: {
  allProducts: [
    { id: 5, name: 'product 5' }
  ]
 }
};

for (let item of Object.values( data) ) {
  for (let product of item.allProducts) {
    console.log(product);
  }
}
```