# How do I loop through a nested object to check if true is found?

Tags: javascript, loops

I have a nested object, I want to loop through a particular property and check if true exists.

If true isn't found I want to return false, otherwise if there is one instance of true I want to stop the loop.

```
let object = {
    firstProperty: 'foo',
    secondProperty: 'bar',
    objectProperty: {
        value1: false,
        value2: false,
        value3: true
}
```

I only want to loop through the objectProperty, and return true if true is found, and false if true is NOT found

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to iterate over a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379274/how-to-iterate-over-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 2):

Check if any of the values is true inside the object.

```js
let object = {
    firstProperty: 'foo',
    secondProperty: 'bar',
    objectProperty: {
        value1: false,
        value2: false,
        value3: true
    }
}


const res = Object.values(object.objectProperty).some(value => value === true)

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, once you get the keys array, everything is simple. You can get that using `Object.keys(obj)` method, that will return an array of keys of the given object. Next, you might simply iterate and check or use a lambda function, in our case, reduce. Node that you iterate through an array of keys, so you have to check `obj[key]` for a particular value.

I added a jsfiddle with two working examples below.

```js
let obj = {
    firstProperty: 'foo',
    secondProperty: 'bar',
    objectProperty: {
        value1: false,
        value2: false,
        value3: true
    }
};

// Method 1
let inner = obj.objectProperty;
let ans = Object.keys(inner).reduce((a, e) => inner[e] || a, false);
console.log(ans);

// Method 2
let found = false;
Object.keys(inner).forEach(key => {
  if (inner[key])
    found = true;
});

console.log(found);
```

Cheers!