# Getting context.config.failTestOn Error Log.exclude Keywords.forEach is not a function error in protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

The following error is occurred when we clicking the sub menus from main menu(Mouse hover).

[image: Error Image]
Help me how to solve this issue.

```
if (browserLogs) {
    browserLogs.forEach(function (log) {
        var logLevel = context.config.failTestOnErrorLog.failTestOnErrorLogLevel ? context.config.failTestOnErrorLog.failTestOnErrorLogLevel : 900;
        var flag = false;
        if (log.level.value > logLevel) { // it's an error log
            if (context.config.failTestOnErrorLog.excludeKeywords) {
                context.config.failTestOnErrorLog.excludeKeywords.forEach(function (keyword) {
                    if (log.message.search(keyword) > -1) {
                        flag = true;
                    }
                });
            }
            expect(log.level.value > logLevel && flag).toEqualBecause(true, 'Error logs present in console:' + require('util').inspect(log));
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: can you show the code you've got, you could have a typo or something else that would tell what the issue is.

Comment: Yeah we will for sure need the code. There is some problem with how you are identifying `Keywords`

Comment: I've downvoted also due to the lack of information. I suspect that your issue lies with fact keywords is likely an elementArray and therefore does not support the foreach method. Try using [each](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.each) if that is the case

Comment: Please find my below code.
The following code i written in my base.js file.
    `this.clickByXpath = function(xpath){
        element(by.xpath(xpath)).click();
        console.log(xpath+" is clicked successfully");
    }  
    this.moveToElement = function(xpath){
        var el = element(by.xpath(xpath));
        browser.actions().mouseMove(el).perform();
    }`

Comment: Then i called this into another js file
 `this.clickMenu = function(){
        base_page.moveToElement(objects.locators.SalesOrganization.menu_xpath);
     base_page.clickByXpath(objects.locators.SalesOrganization.selectMenu_xpath);`

Comment: Thanks for providing that but this seems to be unrelated to your issue. Could you provide the code you are declaring `keywords` and where you are calling that forEach

Comment: Thanks, I didn't used forEach anywhere. My test steps are getting passed but after that i am getting this issue in console.

Comment: i have added index.js forEach code above. please check it.

Comment: Ah I see, originally it appeared keyword was a separate word but the screenshot has cleared things up for me.

Answer (score 0):

As you may know `forEach` is an array operation but I've frequently seen failures with it mistakenly being called on objects.
Can you check if it is definitely an array by including the following two lines?

```
console.log(typeof context.config.failTestOnErrorLog.excludeKeywords);
console.log(Array.isArray(context.config.failTestOnErrorLog.excludeKeywords));
```

It it does turn out to be an object you can still loop over it using [the information in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14379304/10836734).

Hope the helps, let me if it doesn't and I can suggest other options. Have seen this error many times.