# Type casting return from Firebase DB query to an iterable type

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

**What I am trying to do**

I'm currently setting up my Firebase Functions for the DB, for this I am using TypeScript.
I'm trying to get a node from my database. The node is a Map (i.e. Map of String, bool in Java). The problem is that after fetching my node 'test' from my DB I am trying to iterate through its members, but I am getting the error

**The error**

> TypeError: agenda.forEach is not a function
>
> at Object. (\firecast\functions\lib\index.js:32:16)
>
> at Generator.next ()
>
> at fulfilled (\firecast\functions\lib\index.js:4:58)
>
> at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

**My settup**

Here is how I have my DB set up: (Sorry, idk why the image embedding is not working, I'll put the link)

Link to image: https://pasteboard.co/I7KogY2.png

This is my complete function:

```
export const getTest=
functions.https.onRequest(async (request,response)=>{
    try{
        const GlobalCalendar= await admin.firestore().doc("Calendar/GlobalCalendar").get()
        const agenda=GlobalCalendar.data()!.test
        const hours: any[]=[] 
        agenda.forEach((weekday: any) => {
            hours.push(weekday)
        }); 
        response.send(agenda);
    }
    catch(error){
        console.log(error)
        response.status(500).send(error)
    }
})
```

**My try to fix it**

If I comment out

> // const hours: any[]=[]
>
> // agenda.forEach((weekday: any) => {
>
> //     hours.push(weekday)
>
> //     });

it will successfully send the map 'agenda' and I get the following:

> { 
>      "four": true, 
>      "one": true, 
>      "three": true, 
>      "two": true 
>   }

**Conclusion**

So I know that I am getting the node 'test' correctly from the database, but the problem is iterating through this object. Seems like whatever the type of 'agenda' is, it doesn't have the function 'forEach'. I followed instructions from the Firebase youtube video and they did the same work, but unlike mine, theirs worked perfectly.

Link to Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jr7pDZ1RAUg&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLkPZHe41m4jfAxUi0JjLgSM&index=6

My expected result is to be able to iterate through the elements in the variable 'agenda' which is my node 'test' in the image.

Thanks so much for your time!

Comment: So, what exactly is `agenda`?  It sounds like it's not what you think it is.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply @DougStevenson.  'agenda' is the variable where I am trying to save the field 'test' from the document 'GlobalCalendar' or in other words, 'Calendar/GlobalCalendar/test' (maybe the image of my DB will help here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field `test` in your database is an object, not an array.  You can't iterate an object with forEach - it won't have that method, or any iterator method.  If you want to iterate the keys and values of an object, then [try one of these options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379274/how-to-iterate-over-a-javascript-object).

Comment: Thank you so much!! I love your videos in YT btw, pretty helpful. So the problem was solved by using a for(var member in agenda) all thanks to your help and Denys Séguret from the other post