# React JS - data.map can't create list with the data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list

I got `data.js` file with some basic info for food like:

```
export default [
    {
        "name": "Crock Pot Roast",
        "information":[
            {
                "date":"24 July 2019",
                "type": "Main dish",
                "difficulty": "Easy",
                "time": "~50",
            }
        ],
        "ingredients": [
            {
                "quantity": "1",
                "name": " beef roast",
                "type": "Meat"
            }
        ],
        ...
        Some more data
        ...
    }
   ]
```

I want to create list on react that can get all elements from `data.information` which function will be correct to use?

I'm getting the data like this:

```
const getData = data.map(food => {
    return (
        <div key={food.name}>
            <span>{food.name}</span>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <img src={food.imageURL} alt={food.name} />
                    <div>
                        <ul>{getFoodInformation}</ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div>food ingredients</div>

            <div>food recipe</div>
        </div>
    );
});
```

but I can't use `food.information.map` to create list like:

```
<ul>{food.information.map((info) => <div key={info.date}>{info}</div>) }</ul>
```

Any ideas maybe to use another function not map?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to iterate over a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379274/how-to-iterate-over-a-javascript-object)

Comment: What does your ideal/expected HTML look like for the value of `{getFoodInformation}` ? Should each property be contained in a separate `<li />` ?

Answer (score 2):

You're right that this line is the problem:

```
<ul>{food.information.map((info) => <div key={info.date}>{info}</div>) }</ul>
```

*But*, `.map()` is not a problem. Your `information` data *is* an array, so you can `.map()` it with JSX.

Your problem is this:

```
<div key={info.date}>{info}</div>
```

`info` is an object, and React doesn't know how to print an object "beautifully". You want to use the string data (for example, `{info.type}`).

If you need to dump the full object, use `JSON.stringify` like this:

```
<div key={info.date}>{JSON.stringify(info)}</div>
```

Comment: This method works...I was really hoping for more beautiful way to get the data and after that to create list

Comment: You can write a beautiful method that prints the data in whatever format you want, but the baseline is React doesn't know how to print an object. Actually no one would know what you expect to be displayed by putting `<div>{object}</div>`.

Answer (score 0):

React does not render array/object into a list by default. you have to be explicit in your code.

your first attempt is 'close' to correct, however, you can notice, ingredients and information are both arrays of objects. it means that you have to generate a  tag for each index.

I used JSON.stringify to generate a unique key since using an index for key is bad practice.

The code below shows you one of the correct approaches using react.

```js
        const data = [
      {
        name: "Crock Pot Roast",
        imageURL: "https://via.placeholder.com/150",
        information: [
          {
            date: "24 July 2019",
            type: "Main dish",
            difficulty: "Easy",
            time: "~50"
          }
        ],
        ingredients: [
          {
            quantity: "1",
            name: " beef roast",
            type: "Meat"
          }
        ]
      }
    ];

    const CardRecipe = ({data}) => {
      const { name, imageURL, information, ingredients } = data;
      return (
        <div key={name}>
          <span>{name}</span>
          <div>
            <div>
              <img src={imageURL} alt={name} />
              <div>
                {information &&
                  information.map(info => {
                    const { date, type, difficulty, time } = info;
                    return (
                      <ul key={JSON.stringify(info)}>
                        <li> {date} </li>
                        <li> {type} </li>
                        <li> {difficulty} </li>
                        <li> {time} </li>
                      </ul>
                    );
                  })}
              </div>
              <div>
                {ingredients &&
                  ingredients.map(ingredient => {
                    const { quantity, name, type } = ingredient;
                    return (
                      <ul key={JSON.stringify(ingredient)}>
                        <li> {quantity} </li>
                        <li> {name} </li>
                        <li> {type} </li>
                      </ul>
                    );
                  })}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div>food ingredients</div>

          <div>food recipe</div>
        </div>
      );
    };

    export default function App() {
      const first_reciepe = data[0];
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <CardRecipe data={first_reciepe} />
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Alternatively, you can print any lists by mapping once on the array, and then on each object/key to generate (x) amount of <"li"> tags.

Example:

```
const DoList = ({ data }) => {
  return data.map(list => {
    return (
      <ul key={list}>
        {Object.keys(list).map(key => {
          const value = list[key];
          return <li key={key}> {value} </li>;
        })}
      </ul>
    );
  });
};
```

Then you would use it as many time as you want like this:

```
<DoList data={ingredients} />
<DoList data={information} />
<DoList data={...} />
```

Comment: I tried with your method just needed to add:
```
return (
 <React.Fragment>
       <li> {date} </li>
       <li> {type} </li>
       <li> {difficulty} </li>
       <li> {time} </li>
        </React.Fragment>
)
```
it's not giving me errors but the data never show up...
<div>
    <img>
    <div>
        <ul></ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul></ul>
     </div>
</div>
<div>food ingredients</div>
<div>food recipe</div>
DOM look like this after but the ul is empty.

Comment: @A.Salim Indeed, My code is a bit sketchy, I wrote it pretty late last night. I'll update in a minute thanks for pointing out the issues.

Comment: I add another way if you could just check the last comment I like your way I'm trying to do it way more simple and clean to read but it's kind a difficult for me never played that deep with data...and not sure should I use JSON.stringify()....

Comment: You're not forced to use stringify you can use one of the property you have as a key. I checked your edit. It's not possible to do it without mapping as map return elements unlike other loops for/each. Map is the cleanest way to generate new html elements. Eventually what you can do to be a bit cleaner is writing a second reusable component that will handle the lists exclusivly