# Loop through object & create object with required values Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to store some data into object from another object using loop.
i tried

```
jQuery.each(data.forter_request.cartItems, function(index, value) {
          console.log(value);
});
```

Here is the object i am getting

```
 0 :  {basicItemData: {…}, deliveryDetails: {…}}
basicItemData:
category: "Select Items - 20% Off"
name: "Feel The Noize Mini Skirt"
price:
amountLocalCurrency: "90"
amountUSD: "90"
currency: "USD"
__proto__: Object
productId: "362412"
quantity: 2
type: "TANGIBLE"
```

i want to store this data dynamically in below form

```
line_items: [
     {
       product_name: 'Feel The Noize Mini Skirt',
       product_id: '362412',
       product_price: 90.00,
       product_quantity: 2
     },
     {
       product_name: 'Pillows, Large (Set of 2)',
       product_id: '15',
       product_price: 68.00,
       product_quantity: 1
     },
   ]
```

**console.log(initial_object)
returns**

```
{productId: "362412", name: "Feel The Noize Mini Skirt", category: "Select Items - 20% Off", quantity: 1, price: {…}, …}
category: "Select Items - 20% Off"
name: "Feel The Noize Mini Skirt"
price: {amountUSD: "45", amountLocalCurrency: "45", currency: "USD"}
productId: "362412"
quantity: 1
type: "TANGIBLE"
```

s their any way we can do this ?

Comment: Can you clearly specify the object which you want to travesre through, the one mentioned is not in object format, what does basicItemData nand DeliveryDetails, do you need traverse them also.

Comment: Yes i need the data into "line_items" format

Comment: Updated question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys()` to loop through the object keys

So you would have something like

```
var line_items = [];
var fields = ['name','productId','price','quantity']; // Fields you want

jQuery.each(data.forter_request.cartItems, function(index, value) {
      var initial_object = value.basicItemData;
      var new_object = {};
      Object.keys(initial_object).forEach(function(idx,key){
          // Check if the field is among the fields you want to extract
          if(fields.includes(key)){
              new_object[key] = initial_object[key];
          }
      })
      line_items.push(new_object);
});
```

You'll have a list with objects in this format

```
{
    name:'',
    productId:'',
    price:'',
    quantity:''
}
```

You can use it this way or change the property names.

Comment: Thanks for the answer to the question, let me check if that works

Comment: initial_object.keys is not a function

Comment: Could you please log initial_object  and value too ? tell me whats in it

Comment: Sure, let me check that

Comment: Hi @castin i have updated question & added log data for (initial_object)

Comment: HI, edited my answer, it should be `Object.keys(initial_object)`

Comment: Thankyou @castin, let me check with it

Comment: Blank array on console.log(line_items)

Comment: change `new_object["key"] = initial_object["key"];`  to `new_object[key] = initial_object[key];` i.e Just remove the quotes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218666/discussion-between-castin-and-hamendra-sunthwal).

Answer (score 0):

The object you have mentioned does not have a proper format in order to create the `line_items` array. Maybe you can try this. I think the first object should be either array of objects or object of objects so that we can loop through it and construct the `line_items` array. Anyway I will include code for that as well

```js
let myObj = {
  0: {
    basicItemData: {…},
    deliveryDetails: {…}
  },
  basicItemData: null,
  category: "Select Items - 20% Off",
  name: "Feel The Noize Mini Skirt",
  price: "10",
  amountLocalCurrency: "90",
  amountUSD: "90",
  currency: "USD",
  __proto__: Object,
  productId: "362412",
  quantity: 2,
  type: "TANGIBLE",
}


let line_items = [];

let tempObj = {
    product_name: myObj['name'],
    product_id: myObj['productId'],
    product_price: myObj['amountLocalCurrency'],
    product_quantity: myObj['quantity']
  },


  line_items.push(tempObj)
```

> **If you have Array of objects you can try this**

Suppose the above myObj is an array of objects and each object contains the same key-value pairs,

```js
//Here we have array of objects which we can loop through
let myObj = [{
    0: {
      basicItemData: {…},
      deliveryDetails: {…}
    },
    basicItemData: null,
    category: "Select Items - 20% Off",
    name: "Feel The Noize Mini Skirt",
    price: "10",
    amountLocalCurrency: "90",
    amountUSD: "90",
    currency: "USD",
    __proto__: Object,
    productId: "362412",
    quantity: 2,
    type: "TANGIBLE",
  },
  {
    0: {
      basicItemData: {…},
      deliveryDetails: {…}
    },
    basicItemData: null,
    category: "different Select Items - 20% Off",
    name: "different name",
    price: "100",
    amountLocalCurrency: "906",
    amountUSD: "190",
    currency: "USD",
    __proto__: Object,
    productId: "362415",
    quantity: 2,
    type: "TANGIBLE",
  },
  { ...
  },
  { ...
  },
]

let line_items = [];


for (item of myObj) {

  let tempObj = {
    product_name: item['name'],
    product_id: item['productId'],
    product_price: item['amountLocalCurrency'],
    product_quantity: item['quantity']
  }
  line_items.push(tempObj)
}
```

**If the structure is different and you need to loop through slightly different wat then check out [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62592300/9920947) link.**

Comment: Thankyou for the answer to the question.

Comment: Hello, it gives me output but how can i make sure the "line_items" has the same format that i want ?

Comment: you have to modify "tempObj" accordingly