# Difference between i and window[i] in for statement

Tags: javascript, for-loop, variables, console, window

Why is

```
for (var i in window) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

interpreted differently from

```
for (var i in window) {
    console.log(window[i]);
}
```

?
When I ran the first script, I got the window object's properties (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp) and its methods. However, when I ran the second script, I got the window's objects and functions. Why is `console.log(i)` different from `console.log(window[i])`?

Comment: The first outputs the property name, the second outputs the property value. It's called "square bracket notation"

Comment: @evolutionxbox Okay, thank you - can you make that an official answer so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to iterate over a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379274/how-to-iterate-over-a-javascript-object) or [Iterate through object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties)