# Loop through objects from fetch response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object

I am trying to loop through the array of objects below to get the data value in this format:

Market_Name, District_Name, State, Commodity, Variety, datetimes, Price

```
{
    "Market_Name":{
       "0":"A lot",
       "1":"A lot",
       "2":"A lot",
       "3":"A lot",
       "4":"A lot",
       "5":"A lot"
    },
    "District_Name":{
       "0":"Ratlam",
       "1":"Ratlam",
       "2":"Ratlam",
       "3":"Ratlam",
       "4":"Ratlam",
       "5":"Ratlam"
    },
    "State":{
       "0":"AP",
       "1":"AP",
       "2":"AP",
       "3":"AP",
       "4":"AP",
       "5":"AP"
    },
    "Commodity":{
       "0":"Wheat",
       "1":"Wheat",
       "2":"Wheat",
       "3":"Wheat",
       "4":"Wheat",
       "5":"Wheat"
    },
    "Variety":{
       "0":"Medium",
       "1":"Medium",
       "2":"Medium",
       "3":"Medium",
       "4":"Medium",
       "5":"Medium"
    },
    "datetimes":{
       "0":"2020-01-01",
       "1":"2020-01-02",
       "2":"2020-01-03",
       "3":"2020-01-04",
       "4":"2020-01-05",
       "5":"2020-01-06"
    },
    "Price":{
       "0":"1981",
       "1":"1970",
       "2":"1981",
       "3":"1970",
       "4":"1968",
       "5":"1974"
    }
 }
```

I have done some scripting but none seems get the desired result of what I want. Can anyone assist on how to solve this?

Comment: Please check the following [How to iterate object in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379274/how-to-iterate-over-a-javascript-object) and [How to iterate an array in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: can you share some code ?

Comment: Actually I have cleared it because it wasn't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have an array; you have an object. You should use `Object.entries`, at which point you can simply `reduce`.

You haven't given your *exact* target shape, but I can only assume it's something like this.

```js
const data = {
  "Market_Name": {
    "0":"A lot", "1":"A lot", "2":"A lot",
    "3":"A lot", "4":"A lot", "5":"A lot",
  },
  "District_Name":{
    "0":"Ratlam", "1":"Ratlam", "2":"Ratlam",
    "3":"Ratlam", "4":"Ratlam", "5":"Ratlam",
  },
  "State":{
    "0":"AP", "1":"AP", "2":"AP",
    "3":"AP", "4":"AP", "5":"AP",
  },
  "Commodity":{
    "0":"Wheat", "1":"Wheat", "2":"Wheat",
    "3":"Wheat", "4":"Wheat", "5":"Wheat"
  },
  "Variety":{
    "0":"Medium", "1":"Medium", "2":"Medium",
    "3":"Medium", "4":"Medium", "5":"Medium",
  },
  "datetimes":{
    "0":"2020-01-01", "1":"2020-01-02", "2":"2020-01-03",
    "3":"2020-01-04", "4":"2020-01-05", "5":"2020-01-06",
  },
  "Price":{
    "0":"1981", "1":"1970", "2":"1981",
    "3":"1970", "4":"1968", "5":"1974",
  },
};
 
const transformed = Object.values(Object.entries(data)
  .reduce((acc, [ key, value ]) => {
    Object.values(value).forEach((data, i) => {
      if (!acc[i]) acc[i] = { };
      acc[i][key] = data;
    });
    return acc;
  }, {  }));
  
console.log(transformed);
```

This builds an object that looks like

```js
{
  "0": { /* [market_name][0], [district_name][0] */ },
  "1": { /* [market_name][1], [district_name][1] */ },
  /* and so on... */
  "n": { /* [field_name_1][n], [field_name_n][n] */ }
}
```

and then uses `Object.values` to get an array out of it. Using an Object for a middle step allows us to add things at arbitary indexes before reducing it back down to an array.

---

Here is the same thing, writtin with classic `for`-loops instead of `.reduce`. It will perhaps be a little easier to follow.

```js
const data = {
  "Market_Name": {
    "0":"A lot", "1":"A lot", "2":"A lot",
    "3":"A lot", "4":"A lot", "5":"A lot",
  },
  "District_Name":{
    "0":"Ratlam", "1":"Ratlam", "2":"Ratlam",
    "3":"Ratlam", "4":"Ratlam", "5":"Ratlam",
  },
  "State":{
    "0":"AP", "1":"AP", "2":"AP",
    "3":"AP", "4":"AP", "5":"AP",
  },
  "Commodity":{
    "0":"Wheat", "1":"Wheat", "2":"Wheat",
    "3":"Wheat", "4":"Wheat", "5":"Wheat"
  },
  "Variety":{
    "0":"Medium", "1":"Medium", "2":"Medium",
    "3":"Medium", "4":"Medium", "5":"Medium",
  },
  "datetimes":{
    "0":"2020-01-01", "1":"2020-01-02", "2":"2020-01-03",
    "3":"2020-01-04", "4":"2020-01-05", "5":"2020-01-06",
  },
  "Price":{
    "0":"1981", "1":"1970", "2":"1981",
    "3":"1970", "4":"1968", "5":"1974",
  },
};

const alteredKeys = { };

for (const [ key, nested ] of Object.entries(data)) {
  for (const [ i, value ] of Object.entries(nested)) {
    if (!alteredKeys[i]) alteredKeys[i] = { };
    alteredKeys[i][key] = value;
  }
}

const transformed = Object.values(alteredKeys);

console.log(transformed);
```

Comment: Your assumption about how the data would look like was spot. It worked and many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can clean up code by creating index/name for rows and cols. Find number of rows and the name of columns. And traverse the data.

```js
const combine = (obj) => {
  const cols = Object.keys(obj);
  const rows = Object.keys(obj["Market_Name"]);

  return rows.map((rowId) =>
    cols.reduce((m, colId) => {
      m[colId] = obj[colId][rowId];
      return m;
    }, {})
  );
};

//Simple version

const combine2 = (obj) => {
  const cols = Object.keys(obj);
  //take first col keys as rows count
  const noOfRows = Object.keys(obj[cols[0]]).length;
  let rows = [];
  for (let rowId = 0; rowId < noOfRows; rowId++) {
    let row = {};
    for (let col of cols) {
      row[col] = obj[col][rowId];
    }
    rows.push(row);
  }
  return rows;
};
const data = {
  Market_Name: {
    0: "A lot",
    1: "A lot",
    2: "A lot",
    3: "A lot",
    4: "A lot",
    5: "A lot",
  },
  District_Name: {
    0: "Ratlam",
    1: "Ratlam",
    2: "Ratlam",
    3: "Ratlam",
    4: "Ratlam",
    5: "Ratlam",
  },
  State: {
    0: "AP",
    1: "AP",
    2: "AP",
    3: "AP",
    4: "AP",
    5: "AP",
  },
  Commodity: {
    0: "Wheat",
    1: "Wheat",
    2: "Wheat",
    3: "Wheat",
    4: "Wheat",
    5: "Wheat",
  },
  Variety: {
    0: "Medium",
    1: "Medium",
    2: "Medium",
    3: "Medium",
    4: "Medium",
    5: "Medium",
  },
  datetimes: {
    0: "2020-01-01",
    1: "2020-01-02",
    2: "2020-01-03",
    3: "2020-01-04",
    4: "2020-01-05",
    5: "2020-01-06",
  },
  Price: {
    0: "1981",
    1: "1970",
    2: "1981",
    3: "1970",
    4: "1968",
    5: "1974",
  },
};
console.log(combine(data));
console.log(combine2(data));
```