# how to get the object key if the object and array value matches in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, array-map

I would like to know how to compare object value and array value
in javascript

if the `array value` and `object value` is same, then how to return the

`object key` value in javascript

```
var result = obj.values(obj).includes(arr2) ? 
'status: active' : 'status: inactive'

var obj = {
  "active": 12,
  "inactive": 14
  "neutral": 16
}

var arr1=[12]
var arr2=[12, 14]
var arr3=[12, 16]
```

```
Expected Output

//for arr1
status: active
// for arr2
status: active
status: neutral
// for arr3
status: active
status: inactive
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to iterate over a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379274/how-to-iterate-over-a-javascript-object)

Comment: Your latest edit seems to have the expected output swapped for arr2 and arr3

Comment: @Terry, thanks for reply, for any array passed, should return the object key value if object value  matches with array value

Comment: Yes, then arr2 should return 'active, inactive' and arr3 should return 'active, neutral'. Your expected output is incorrectly swapped for arr2 and arr3.

Comment: What is output format should be?  Is it just array`['active', 'inactive']` or array of objects`[{ status: 'active' }, { status: 'inactive' }]` ?

Comment: @AlexandrBelan thanks for reply, array of objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply iterate through the array, and then attempt to fetch the `[key, value]` tuples returned by [`Object.entries(obj)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) whose `value` matches the array value. Once found, you return the `key` in the tuple, i.e.:

```
arr.map(v => Object.entries(obj).find(x => x[1] === v)[0]);
```

**Note**: If you array may contain values that are *not* present in the object, the code above will throw an error because `.find()` will return undefined. If that's the case, you need to catch cases where an invalid value is used (defensive design):

```
arr.map(v => {
  const foundTuple = Object.entries(obj).find(x => x[1] === v);
  return foundTuple ? foundTuple[0] : null;
});
```

See proof-of-concept below:

```js
const obj = {
  "active": 12,
  "inactive": 14,
  "neutral": 16
}

const arr1 = [12];
const arr2 = [12, 14];
const arr3 = [12, 16];
const invalid_arr = [12, 999];

function getKeys(obj, arr) {
  return arr.map(v => {
    const foundTuple = Object.entries(obj).find(x => x[1] === v);
    return foundTuple ? foundTuple[0] : null;
  });
}

console.log(getKeys(obj, arr1));
console.log(getKeys(obj, arr2));
console.log(getKeys(obj, arr3));
console.log(getKeys(obj, invalid_arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check that the array includes the object value, not vice-versa:

```js
function* matches(object, array) {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object)) {
    if (array.includes(value))
      yield key;
  }
};

for (const match of matches(obj, arr1))
  console.log(`status: ${match}`);

for (const match of matches(obj, arr2))
  console.log(`status: ${match}`);

for (const match of matches(obj, arr3))
  console.log(`status: ${match}`);
```

This should work.

Comment: thanks for reply, but i should return the object key value instead of true or false

Comment: then I've changed the return with `[key, value]` but it wasn't written anywhere in the initial question. I hope this answers.

Comment: thanks for helping, this doesnt work, have updated my code,

Comment: OK, I think you have exactly the output you're after with my latest changes.

Answer (score 0):

Another one solution

```js
const obj = { "active": 12, "inactive": 14, "neutral": 16 }

const arr1 = [12];
const arr2 = [12, 14];
const arr3 = [12, 16];

const getStatuses= (obj, arr) => arr
  .map(arrValue => {
    const [status] = Object.entries(obj)
      .find(([objKey, objValue]) => objValue === arrValue) 
      ?? [null];
    return { status };
  });

console.log(getStatuses(obj, arr1));
console.log(getStatuses(obj, arr2));
console.log(getStatuses(obj, arr3));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the keys using `Object.keys()` and then filter them by taking the value from the original object, and checking if it's included in the array:

```js
const getStatus = (obj, arr) => Object.keys(obj)
  .filter(key => arr.includes(obj[key]))
  
const obj = { "active": 12, "inactive": 14, "neutral": 16 }

const arr1 = [12];
const arr2 = [12, 14];
const arr3 = [12, 16];

console.log(getStatus(obj, arr1));
console.log(getStatus(obj, arr2));
console.log(getStatus(obj, arr3));
```