# How do I validate number range in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

When I `console.log(req.body.sectionAData)`, I got this result:

```
{
  sectionAData: { AQ1: '5', AQ2: '4', AQ3: '5' }
}
```

So I continue with this:

```
const { AQ1, AQ2, AQ3} = req.body.sectionAData   
console.log( AQ1, AQ2, AQ3)
```

and the result is:

```
5 4 5
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to validate all the AQ1, AQ2 and AQ3 are within the range of 1 to 5

If either one is not in range, then json.send a message.

How should I go about it? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to iterate over a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379274/how-to-iterate-over-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
const check = [AQ1, AQ2, AQ3].every(e => e >= 1 && e <= 5)
if (!check) { 
  // do stuff 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like below, with a `checkRange` helper function:

```js
const checkRange=(v)=> v>=1 && v <=5;

if(checkRange(AQ1) && checkRange(AQ2) && checkRange(AQ3)){
  // send ok response
}else{
  // send bad response
}
```