# Access most recent value in JSON nested object with JS

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to access the most recent element in the `Time Series (5 min)` object, without having to specify the date/time, after using this JS code:

```
var getStock = new XMLHttpRequest();
getStock.open("GET","https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=IBM&interval=5min&apikey=demo", false);
getStock.send(null);

var current_stock = JSON.parse(getStock.responseText);
console.log(current_stock);
var current_stock_price = current_stock["Time Series (5min)"][0]["4. close"];
```

So in this case (see screenshot) it's `Time Series (5 min)` > `2022-04-21 20:00:00` -> `4. close`, but I get an undefined error.

I even tried in the developer console with the full JSON file.
Using `current_stock["Time Series (5 min)"]` returns all of the child values in the console,  but adding `[0]` or `["2022-04-21 20:00:00"]` to the end throws an undefined error.

[image: Raw JSON]

Comment: `current_stock["Time Series (5min)"]` is an object with keys `"2022-04-21 20:00:00"`, `"2022-04-21 19:55:00"`, etc. It's not an array that can be indexed with `[0]`.

Comment: You could use `Object.keys()` to get the keys for `current_stock["Time Series (5min)"]`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it like this:

```js
var getStock = new XMLHttpRequest();
getStock.open("GET", "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=IBM&interval=5min&apikey=demo", false);
getStock.send(null);
var current_stock = JSON.parse(getStock.responseText);

const timeSeries = current_stock['Time Series (5min)']
const key = Object.keys(timeSeries)[0]
console.log(timeSeries[key]['4. close'])
```

Comment: I want to access the latest one, rather than choosing a specific date/time

Comment: Oh, I see, I edit it now

Comment: Thank you, I tried this, but it says `Cannot convert undefined or null to object` on the `const key = Object.keys(timeSeries)[0];` line

Comment: I checked in on my local computer, and it's working. Can you give me more detail about the issue?

Comment: I've used your code exactly. It doesn't work when you run the code snippet here on Stackoverflow as well

Comment: Added console.log and check it out now, please.

Comment: @tristanojbacon the example is also using `apikey=demo` which might have some restrictions (I got error message the first time). You sould create a key here (but do not post it to SO): https://www.alphavantage.co/support/#api-key

Comment: Yes, I'm using my own API key on my side, but shared the demo version for testing

Answer (score 0):

When I change [0] to ["2022-04-21 20:00:00"], like you suggested it works just fine. The code will then be:

```js
var getStock = new XMLHttpRequest();
getStock.open("GET","https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=IBM&interval=5min&apikey=demo", false);
getStock.send(null);

var current_stock = JSON.parse(getStock.responseText);
var current_stock_price = current_stock["Time Series (5min)"]["2022-04-21 20:00:00"]["4. close"];
console.log(current_stock_price)
```

If you don't want to use the keys you can use `Object.values()` to access the data:

```
var getStock = new XMLHttpRequest();
getStock.open("GET","https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=IBM&interval=5min&apikey=demo", false);
getStock.send(null);

var current_stock = JSON.parse(getStock.responseText);
var current_stock_price = Object.values(current_stock["Time Series (5min)"])[0]["4. close"];
console.log(current_stock_price)
```

This will return the latest entry.

Comment: Yes, but as I covered in the question, I want to access the latest one. Having to know the date/time before hand wouldn't get the latest one

Answer (score 0):

That is because current_stock["Time Series (5min)"] is an object. Not an array, that's why the 0 index is not available. If you want to access the first item on current_stock["Time Series (5min)"] here's something you can do

```
var getStock = new XMLHttpRequest();
getStock.open("GET","https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=IBM&interval=5min&apikey=demo", false);
getStock.send(null);

var current_stock = JSON.parse(getStock.responseText);
console.log(current_stock);
var keys = Object.keys(current_stock["Time Series (5min)"]); // return all the keys in current_stock["Time Series (5min)"] object
console.log(keys) // keys is array, so you can access first item as keys[0]
var current_stock_price = current_stock["Time Series (5min)"][keys[0]]["4. close"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to access object as an array.

`current_stock["Time Series (5min)"]["2022-04-21 20:00:00"]["4. close"]` should make you example code work.

To answer you question though on how to loop this, you should convert the object into array.

One example would be to use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), like so:

```js
stock_date_prices = Object.entries(current_stock['Time Series (5min)'])

for (const [datetime, prices] in stock_date_prices) {
  console.log("The closing price at %s was %s", datetime, prices['4. close'])
}
```

For a more elaborate answer on how to loop javascript objects, check [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14379304/1119550).

Comment: I don't need to loop through it, I just want the first/latest element

Comment: Oh, I see - in that case @mohammad-hooshdar answer is correct ;) 
I also updated your post title accordingly.

Comment: I just saw your edit, and realised I'd said Loop - my mistake! Thanks for correcting it