# TypeError: groupBy(...).map is not a function

Tags: javascript

I tried to group json data with specific key like that:

```
function groupBy(items) {
    return items.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      if (curr.league?.id) {
        const { id } = curr.league;
        const currentItems = acc[id];
    
        return { 
          ...acc,
          [id]: currentItems ? [...currentItems, curr] : [curr]
        };
      }
      return acc;
    }, {});
  }

    console.log(groupBy(matches))
```

[Then I get a correct result like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piLe1.png)

but when I tried to get data using `The map() method` like that :

`groupBy(matches).map((match, index) => ( ..... ))`

I get this error :

`groupBy(...).map is not a function TypeError: groupBy(...).map is not a function`

Any Idea?

**EDIT**

[console.log(value) give me this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G55lm.png)

Then I did like this :

```
  Object.entries(groupBy(matches)).
  map(([key, value]) => {
                        console.log(value.league)
                        })
```

I get `20 undefined`

**EDIT 2**

Now I didi like that

```
  Object.entries(groupBy(matches)).forEach(([index, value]) => {
    value.map(([index, match]) => {
  <MatchMonthCard match={match} index={index} key={index}/>
  })
  })
```

but I get new error :

```
object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
```

Comment: `but I get new error` why are you destructuring an object as an array inside value.map

Comment: @James because no solution is working?! you can provide a clear code please?

Comment: It’s unclear what you want the final result to be.  You’ve only recently shown that you are building a react component

Answer (score 0):

Your `groupBy` function intakes an array, but returns an object.  The `.map` function is only available for arrays. To iterate over any object you can use a `forin` loop, or map over the objects keys with `Object.keys`.

This answer does a great job covering how to map over an object: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14810722/7638738

Answer (score 0):

`groupBy` is returning an object and `.map` is native to arrays. Using `Object.keys`, which is the equivalent of `.map` to iterate over an object.

Check [this answer out on](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14379304/22931682) how to make use of it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you want to do by `map` on object, but you can go through the entries of it like this:

```
Object.entries(groupBy(matches)).map(([key, value]) => {
    return something
});
```

or use `Object.keys` to get just the keys or `Object.values` for just the values.

Comment: I get this error : Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop ... of type `array` supplied to ..., expected `object`.

Comment: @TechnicIT Looking at your update, I think you want `Object.entries(groupBy(matches)).map(([key, value]) => value.league)`

Comment: Yes console.log(value[0]?.league) give me a result of the first team, but is a loop I want to get all leagues grouped by ID one by one?

Comment: @TechnicIT Sorry I'm lost. if your just looping over it you don't need map? i did forget that value was an array, so you can loop it like `Object.entries(groupBy(matches)).forEach(([key, values]) => values.forEach(value => console.log(key, value))`

Comment: I did not get you really can you update your post not in comment with clear code

Comment: @TechnicIT sorry man I don't get what your trying to do. i cant tell if that code is what you want. maybe you could explain what you want the result to be?

Comment: Please you can see the second picture above, what I want is to get those results using map, `console.log(value[0]?.league)` return result but just  the first league of ID=0, as I said I want to get all results as shown in picture, but  `console.log(value?.league)` not working?

Comment: @TechnicIT Please try `Object.entries(groupBy(matches)).forEach(([key, value]) => console.log(value.map(val => val.league)))`, hope it helps

Comment: @TechnicIT um you sure? i tried that with my own test data and its logging the leagues in an array fine.

Comment: Your way is working for test, can you check my new edit I get NEW ERROR?

Comment: @TechnicIT if u want match as the whole object, then looks like this `Object.entries(groupBy(matches)).map(([key, value]) => value.map((match, index) => <MatchMonthCard match={match} index={index} key={key + '_' + index}/>))`

Comment: Now is working correctly, I have a new issue please, inside map loop I have the name of league is repeated the number of loop operation but I want the name pf league just one time for every ID to put it in head?

Comment: the code of header is  `<div className="card_header d-flex flex-column g-10">
            <LeagueHeader img={league?.logo} title={league?.name} subtitle={league?.country} />
            </div>`?

Answer (score 0):

You have an algorithm that uses array reduce to create an object containing grouped data, and you want to extract an array of its values.  It's a pretty common pattern to use

```
return Object.values(items.reduce(...))
```

Comment: I tried with object.values I get this error `Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop ... of type `array` supplied to , expected `object`.` ??

Comment: The `…` is there to represent your current reduce function.

Comment: Yes of course but the same error

Comment: check my update pleaseabove

Comment: In your new update you are expecting `value` to be an object with a league property, but by your own design it’s an array of teams that are in the same league.  value[0].league would show the league of the first team of the grouped array.

Comment: Yes `console.log(value[0]?.league)` give me a result of the first team, but is a loop I want to get all leagues grouped by ID one by one?

Answer (score 0):

you have a object first convert to array then Do the map operation

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).