# Is there a good way to iterate over all the subproperties of a Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, properties, iteration

Given I have a javascript object, is there a way to iterate over all the primitive subproperties?

For instance, if I have an object

```
{
  foo: 17,
  bar: {
    a: 2,
    b: 7
  }
}
```

I would like to iterate over foo, bar.a, and bar.b.

Please keep in mind I prefer to iterate over Object.keys() rather than using a for/in loop, although I'm sure I could translate any for/in loop responses into an Object.keys() iteration.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: What you are looking for is called `Object Reflection`

Comment: I could right a function that recursively checks all objects for properties and returns an array of primitive properties, but I was wondering if there was a standard or built-in way of doing it.

Comment: @Joe Is that a concept, or an actual function? Could you give me a code example please?

Comment: There is no built-in support for recursive enumeration of object properties in JavaScript.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a recursive function like this:

```
var x = {
    foo: 17,
    bar: {
        a: 2,
        b: 7
    }
}

function parseObject(something) {
    var keys = Object.keys(something);
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        if (typeof something[keys[i]] === 'object') parseObject(something[keys[i]])
        else console.log(keys[i] + " : " + something[keys[i]]);
    }
}
parseObject(x);
```

Which generates the output:

```
foo : 17 
a : 2 
b : 7
```

A note on this function. It recurses over anything that is an object.  For instance, if you had an array in the object, you would get separate lines for each item in the array.

So for the following object:

```
var x = {
    foo: 17,
    bar: {
        a: 2,
        b: 7
    },
    foobar: [1,2,3]    
}
```

The output would appear:

```
foo : 17 
a : 2 
b : 7 
0 : 1 
1 : 2 
2 : 3
```

There are obviously ways to handle this, but you will need to tailor the function to meet your requirements.

Comment: OK thank you, I can see how that would definitely work for what I need. I wanted to check if there is a built-in function or more standard way to do this, but barring that, this is what I would use.

Comment: It fails when `something[keys[i]]` is `null` because `typeof null === 'object'` is true. Then error thrown is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object" I would add `if(something[keys[i]])` to the original condition to ensure it's truthy.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: This is how you can do it (taken from one of the links below):

```
for (var key in validation_messages) {
   var obj = validation_messages[key];
   for (var prop in obj) {
      alert(prop + " = " + obj[prop]);
   }
}
```

This is a possible duplicate of   :

[Iterate through object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/javascript-iterate-through-object-properties)

[How to Loop through plain JavaScript object with objects as members?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921789/how-to-loop-through-javascript-object-literal-with-objects-as-members)

you can find your answer in the above posts.

Comment: Linking to other SO questions without adding value is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: These questions are asking about iterating through properties; I'm looking to iterate through properties and subproperties recursively.

Comment: I also want to cover an arbitrary depth, so I want the primitive properties, plus the primitive subproperties of the non-primitive properties, plus the primitive subproperties of the non-primitive subproperties of the non-primitive properties, etc.

Comment: you can add a check and make it a recursive call based on checking of the element is an object using `typeof element === 'object';`.