# HTML5, JavaScript and drawing multiple rectangles in a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Why won't my multiple rectangles draw in the canvas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid red">
      <p>Your browser doesn't support canvas.</p>
    </canvas>
  </body>
</html>

<script type ="text/javascript">  
  function Shape(x, y, w, h, fill) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.fill = fill;
  }

  // get canvas element.
  var elem = document.getElementById('myCanvas');

  // check if context exist
  if (elem.getContext) {

    var myRect = [];

    myRect.push(new Shape(10, 0, 25, 25, "#333"))
    myRect.push(new Shape(0, 40, 39, 25, "#333"))
    myRect.push(new Shape(0, 80, 100, 25, "#333"))

    context = elem.getContext('2d');
    for (i in myRect) {

      //console.log(x);

      context.fillRect(i.x, i.y, i.w, i.h)
    }
    //// x, y, width, height
    //context.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);

    //// x, y, width, height      
    //context.fillRect(75, 0, 50, 50);
  }
</script>
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: I'll take a look at your code in a second but just wanted to let you know that the jCanvas plugin for jQuery simplifies drawing on the canvas a lot. You may want to take a look at it. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok, so you were almost there.
When you iterate round your array of rectangles, you are iterating over the array **key** not the objects themselves (see [How to Loop through plain JavaScript object with objects as members?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921789/how-to-loop-through-javascript-object-literal-with-objects-as-members)).
Plus, as @jimjimmy1995 pointed out, you need to set the fill using `.fillStyle` as .`fillRect` does not have a fill parameter.

This code will work:

```
function Shape(x, y, w, h, fill) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.fill = fill;
}

// get canvas element.
var elem = document.getElementById('myCanvas');

// check if context exist
if (elem.getContext) {

    var myRect = [];

    myRect.push(new Shape(10, 0, 25, 25, "#333"));
    myRect.push(new Shape(0, 40, 39, 25, "#333"));
    myRect.push(new Shape(0, 80, 100, 25, "#333"));

    context = elem.getContext('2d');
    for (var i in myRect) {
        oRec = myRect[i];
        context.fillStyle = oRec.fill;
        context.fillRect(oRec.x, oRec.y, oRec.w, oRec.h);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't you need to give it the fill color?

```
context.fillStyle = i.fill;
context.fillRect(i.x,i.y,i.w,i.h);
```

Comment: Yep, you're right - but this is not the major issue - there's a problem with getting the array values in the loop.

Comment: You seem to be missing a few line terminators. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Hehe no problem; It get to a point where you start finishing sentences with a semi-colon not just code; :P