# HTML5 print array of rectangles error

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

[HTML5, JavaScript and drawing multiple rectangles in a canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15220003/html-5-and-drawing-multiple-rectangles-in-a-canvas)

So I have spend the last 2 hours puzzling myself why this wont work, I have followed all the code in the above question but yet it still wont work for me what am I doing wrong?

I added in a square to make sure it was getting to that line and actually working

http://jsfiddle.net/Wh5YX/

```
function Shape(a,b,w,h,fill){

    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.fill = fill;

}

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
if (canvas.getContext){
var myRect = [];

    myRect.push(new Shape(100, 0, 25, 25, "#333"));
    myRect.push(new Shape(0, 40, 39, 25, "#333"));
    myRect.push(new Shape(0, 80, 100, 25, "#333"));

ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
for (i in myRect) {
    oblock = myRect[i];
    ctx.fillStyle = oblock.fill;
    ctx.fillRect(oblock.x,oblock.y,oblock.w,oblock.h);
    ctx.fillStyle="#CC00FF"; 
ctx.fillRect(100,100,20,20); 
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem to be a simple typo in the `Shape` object:

```
function Shape(a,b,w,h,fill){

    this.x = a; /// change to this.x
    this.y = b; /// change to this.y

    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.fill = fill;
}
```

**[Updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/Wh5YX/3/)**

or you could reduce the risk of typos such as this (in general) by providing the proper variable names, for example:

```
function Shape(x, y, w, h, fill){

    this.x = x;  /// now we see the link more clearly
    this.y = y;

    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.fill = fill;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot ! late at night head is tired !! New to javascript aswell so just getting use to it ! thanks again man!