# Drawing multiple squares on the canvas

Tags: javascript, object, html5-canvas

I was wondering why my squares weren't drawing on the canvas. I saw a different post similar to mine, but I couldn't manage to fix my code

```
var squares = [];
var ctx;
function startGame() {
    ctx = document.getElementById("myCanvas").getContext("2d");
    squares.push(drawStuff(75, 75, "red", 10, 10));
    squares.push(drawStuff(75, 75, "yellow", 50, 60));
    squares.push(drawStuff(75, 75, "blue", 10, 220));
    for ( i=0;i<squares.length;i++){
        ctx.fillStyle = squares[i].color;
        ctx.fillRect(squares[i].left,squares[i].top,squares[i].width,squares[i].height);
    }
}
function drawStuff(width, height, color, x, y) {
    var shape;
    shape.left = x;
    shape.top = y;
    shape.width = width;
    shape.height = height;
    shape.color = color;
    return shape;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [html 5 and drawing multiple rectangles in a canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15220003/html-5-and-drawing-multiple-rectangles-in-a-canvas)

Comment: But the answer in that other question is almost exactly the same as the answer in this one, and both are about drawing multiple squares on a canvas. If the OP uses the answer from the other question, he'll have the same end result.

Comment: @markE; I'm more of a "give a man a fish, he'll eat for a day" kind of person. You've solved the immediate problem, but that just means the OP knows they can just come to SO and get instant fixes for the rest of their issues. It's also less likely to help future visitors.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan. Sure, there are vampire questions on SO, but this question doesn't seem to be one of those. Hope said he/she (1) tried to fix their own issues, but (2) couldn't get their code running so then (3) asked their question on SO. Seems appropriate for SO. Anyway, I respect your stance but I differ slightly. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close!

**You have a couple of issues in your code:**

- You must call startGame() to run its code.
- You must define `shape` as an object: `var shape={}`.

```js
var squares = [];
var ctx;
startGame();
function startGame() {
    ctx = document.getElementById("myCanvas").getContext("2d");
    squares.push(drawStuff(75, 75, "red", 10, 10));
    squares.push(drawStuff(75, 75, "yellow", 50, 60));
    squares.push(drawStuff(75, 75, "blue", 10, 220));
    for ( i=0;i<squares.length;i++){
        ctx.fillStyle = squares[i].color;
        ctx.fillRect(squares[i].left,squares[i].top,squares[i].width,squares[i].height);
    }
}
function drawStuff(width, height, color, x, y) {
    var shape={};
    shape.left = x;
    shape.top = y;
    shape.width = width;
    shape.height = height;
    shape.color = color;
    return shape;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: Who downvoted this? This is a correct answer, here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pcdx9vky/

Comment: Seems a straightforward Q&A about a few glitches in the code. Why the downvote?