# How to three different shape triangle in single page using canvas method?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(150, 150);
ctx.lineTo(300, 150);
ctx.lineTo(225, 75);
ctx.lineTo(150, 150);

ctx.stroke();

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Hi I have some code in canvas method to draw in triangle but i want to draw the different shapes of 3 triangle in single page how to programming in that method please help me.

i added one example picture that modal i want to canvas method:

[image: i added one example picture that modal i want to canvas method.]

Comment: Give a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15220003/html5-javascript-and-drawing-multiple-rectangles-in-a-canvas

Comment: Do you understand how the code you've shown works? You just have to repeat it or put it in a loop and apply appropriate coordinates for the additional shapes. (Or, better, put it in a function that takes the coordinates as arguments.) What is the specific problem you're having extending that code?

Comment: @nnnnnn i want to single page to shown 3 triangle shape in canvas but i try to same loop apply the condition but not working how to modified.

Comment: There's no loop nor condition in your code example, please show the code you have.

Comment: You received a proper answer on your original question -- 3 proper answers(!). If you want 3 triangles then just repeat the drawing code for each of your triangles. You could also put the drawing code into a function and call that function for each of your 3 triangles: `function drawTriangle( x0,y0, x1,y1, x2,y2 ){ ctx.beginPath(); ctx.moveTo(x0,y0); ctx.lineTo(x1,y1); ctx.lineTo(x2,y2); ctx.closePath(); ctx.stroke(); }`