# Append JSON data from Yelp API to html

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, yelp

I tried the JavaScript example from the Yelp developer site. Everything´s working but I wonder how to append the JSON data to an html list (ul). The list should contain restaurants in my town. Does anybody know how to do this?

P.S. PHP would be OK, too.

**Edit:**
Thank you for your answers but it still doesn´t work. I´m not able to give you more details because the Yelp API is poorly documented and I´m new to JSON and PHP.

Comment: You want to create ul list based on data that is in JSON?

Comment: could you provide some of the sample data returned from the server

Comment: Yes, I want to create a ul list.

Comment: The server returns the JSON data just as epected.

Comment: yes but i want the format so i can give you som example of the code

Comment: Hope this helps: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/12953592/prettyprint.png

Comment: need to loop over array and parse to html.... there are lots and lots of posts here and all over the web how to do this. Are you accesing json API from server or javascript?

Comment: from server with this url: http://api.yelp.com/v2/search?term=restaurants&location=Goerlitz

Comment: can pass the json to browser ( as in an AJAX request) and parse to html with javascript, or use `json_decode` to create php array and loop over array on server to create html. Again lots of resources in web search how to do this

Answer (score 0):

If the JSON object is being returned as part of an Ajax request you'll need something vaguely like this:

```
$.post("yourajaxrequest.php", //calls .php file and transmits data via $_POST
                {
                    //variables required by the PHP file go here
                },
                //the function to perform when an object is returned from .php file
                function(toreceive){
                    var obj = JSON.parse(toreceive);
                    var first = obj.returnone;
                });
```

Without reading the Yelp documentation I'm not sure quite how you'll receive the object from Yelp, but the `JSON.parse()` method is the approach you should take to decode the object.

After parsing the object to a variable, you can assign the elements of the object by calling `object.*insert array value here*;`

This would be declared in PHP normally with something similar to:

```
$toencode = "The first string to be encoded";
$tosend['returnone'] = $toencode;
echo json_encode($tosend);
exit;
```

You can then append to a `<ul>` by using `.append`

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="list">
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

In your `<script>`:

```
$('#list').append('<li>'+first+'</li>');
```

Without any sample code or reading the Yelp documentation, there's not a lot more to go on.

Hope it helps.

**edited to add closing bracket and semi-colon to first line of code.

Comment: From the PHP file (https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-api/blob/master/v2/php/example.php): `$response = json_decode($data);`

Comment: OK, so this file is requesting data from Yelp, that's executed in lines 42-47.

This returns a JSON object, which is decoded at line 50 and the resulting data is printed out for the user to see at line 53.

If you held a copy of this file on your webserver and used an Ajax call to it from the client, you could remove lines 50 onwards and instead replace them with:

    echo $response;
    exit;

Comment: There's proper documentation for Ajax calls here: [link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score -1):

assume that outputs of the api call is ["blah", "blah", "blah", "blah"]

```
$("#container").append("<ul>");

$.ajax({
  // options go here

  success: function(datas){
    for(var i in datas){
      var data = datas[i];
       $("#container ul").append("<li>"+data+"</li>");
    }
  }
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cDU52/1/  - fixed

read: http://api.jquery.com/append/

read: [How to Loop through plain JavaScript object with objects as members?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921789/how-to-loop-through-javascript-object-literal-with-objects-as-members)

Comment: not very efficient making an append for every pass of loop. Also you can't write opening and closing tags to the DOM. Your code won't work as shown. `$("#container").append("<ul>");` will create the complete `UL` element then `LI` needs to be appended to `$("#container ul")`

Comment: my code looks like this: $(".ui-content").append("<ul>");

$.ajax({
   'url': message.action,
   'data': parameterMap,
   'cache': true,
   'dataType': 'jsonp',
   'jsonpCallback': 'cb',
   'success': function(datas){
    for(var i in datas){
      var data = datas[i];
       $(".ui-content").append("<li>"+data+"</li>");
    }
  }
});

$(".ui-content").append("</ul>");

Comment: hey @charlietfl, have you ever try reading the doc. http://api.jquery.com/append/ . The .append() does append html string ,not dom object.

Comment: no, your code doesn´t work. The list items are outside of the ul!

Comment: inspect the resultant html in console will see it is invalid html structure. Also `$("#container").append("</ul>");` does nothing because the html string is invalid for jQuery. IE will have all sorts of problems with your code due to invalid html. One other point, `append` will accept a DOM element as argument, or jQuery object. Look at docs closer

Comment: i fixed my code, could you please reconsider my answer and unnegative vote my answer.