# How to get values from json array using javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a PHP file which only return an array with the drivers and a url:

```
{"drivers":[{"marco":[0],"luigi":[123],"Joan":[2444],"George":[25]}, {"marco":[23],"luigi":[3],"Joan":[244],"George":[234]}],"url":"google.es"}
```

Is the json correctly structured?
And I'm trying to get the result using jQuery and AJAX by this way:

```
$.getJSON('calculate.php&someparams=123', function(data) {
    alert("url - " + data.url);
    var arr = data.drivers;

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        alert(arr[i] + " - " + arr[i][0]);
    }
});
```

I see the first alert() with the url, but the second one does not works...
What am I doing wrong?

If you need more info let me know and I'll edit the post.

Comment: _"Is the json correctly structured?"_ Do you mean "is it valid json"? Because the structure looks valid in the sense of not having syntax errors, but whether it is "correct" depends on what you want it to represent. (Though having said that I'd suggest that putting every number in its own array is not necessary unless it is sometimes possible for a name to have more than one number associated with it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `drivers` is not an array, it is an object, you use [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to iterate through the object elements.

```
$.getJSON('calculate.php&someparams=123', function(data) {
    $.each(data.drivers, function(key, value){
        $.each(value, function(key, value){
            console.log(key, value);
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: thanks! but sorry, i've updated the json of the main post... what it would be then?

Comment: @Joëlle what is the output you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

That's an object, not an array. It has named properties, not numerical indexes.

You need a [for in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921789/how-to-loop-through-javascript-object-literal-with-objects-as-members) to loop over the properties.

Answer (score 0):

`drivers` is an object. Not an array.

How about this?

```
var json_string = '{"drivers":{"marco":[0],"luigi":[123],"Joan":[2444],"George":[25]},"url":"google.es"}';
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(json_string);
alert(obj.url);
```