# Loop to Add JSON Value to Array

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a JSON object like so:

```
$scope.object = {
    'thing1': { 
        'content': 'blah blah',
        'order': '1',
},
    'thing2': { 
        'content': 'blah blah blah',
        'order': '2',
    },
}
```

I would like to add the values that correspond with the 'content' keys to an array.I thought this would work:

```
  var things=[];
  for (x in $scope.object){
    things.push(x.content);
  }
```

It does not work. It just returns undefined. Any ideas?

Comment: [Please look at this discussion][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921789/how-to-loop-through-javascript-object-literal-with-objects-as-members

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x` enumerates the keys of `$scope.object`, not the values. Use this instead:

```
things.push($scope.object[x].content);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var things = [], x;
for(x in $scope.object){
    if($scope.object.hasOwnProperty(x)){
        if($scope.object[x].content !== undefined){
            things.push($scope.object[x].content);
        }
    }    
}
```

This covers all checks you should require to make sure its working. Tested:

```
var $scope = {};
$scope.object = {
    'thing1': { 
        'content': 'blah blah',
        'order': '1',
    },
    'thing2': { 
        'content': 'blah blah blah',
        'order': '2',
    }
};

var things = [], x;
for(x in $scope.object){
    if($scope.object.hasOwnProperty(x)){
        if($scope.object[x].content !== undefined){
            things.push($scope.object[x].content);
        }
    }    
}

console.log(things);//logs ["blah blah", "blah blah blah"]
```

`Object.hasOwnProperty(propertyName)` is required to make sure that the object has actually been given that property, `.content` makes sure that the property is there and the value is not undefined.

In the instance of:

```
for(var x in object)
```

`x` is actually the property name, in this case `thing1` and `thing2`, if object is replaced by an array then x will be the index of each object.

Answer (score 0):

instead of writing again all the needed checks, you can use angularJS' wrapper for jquery.foreach:

[live example](http://jsfiddle.net/5WNGJ/)

```js
var result = []
angular.forEach($scope.object, function (value, key) {
    result.push(value.content);
});
```