# What is the object equivalent of _.pluck

Tags: javascript, object, underscore.js, transformation

I've re-implemented my own version of what I need but I suspect this is already included in underscore since it's so simple and so closely related to many other functions. But I can't think of what it should be called.

Basically, what I want is a version of _.pluck that works with objects and returns an object instead of an array (with its associated keys).

So, for instance, if I had an object like this:

```
elements: {
    steam: {
        temperature: 100,
        color: 'orange',
        state: 'gas'
    },
    water: {
        temperature: 50,
        color: 'blue',
        state: 'liquid'
    },
    ice: {
        temperature: 0,
        color: 'white',
        state: 'solid'
    }
}
```

I'd want to call `_.something(elements, 'temperature')`

And have it return

```
{
    steam: 100,
    water: 50,
    ice: 0
}
```

Instead of `_.pluck(elements, 'temperature')` which returns

```
[100, 50, 0]
```

What is this transformation called and is it already included in underscore? I've written a quick version myself with jQuery's each loop since I'm more familiar with jQuery than underscore (included below) but would prefer to use one from the library if possible.

```
$.objPluck = function(obj, key) {
    var ret = {};
    $.each(obj, function(k, value) {
        ret[k] = value[key];
    });
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: There's the `Array.map` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) which is basically what you're doing, but with an object

Comment: Is there a way to make `Array.map` preserve keys?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. And anyways, I was just referring to your initial concern of `But I can't think of what it should be called`. With arrays, I'd call this "mapping"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no method to do exactly this in underscore **1.4.4**, but if you want to stay in underscore, you can do

```
_.object(_.keys(elements), _.pluck(elements, 'temperature'))
```

[Demo at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PfZwx/) courtesy of [bfavaretto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/825789/bfavaretto)

---

As of underscore **1.8.3**, this can be done succinctly with `_.mapObject(elements, 'temperature');`.

[Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PfZwx/44/)

Comment: I was going to post the exact same code. Here's a jsfiddle to demonstrate it: http://jsfiddle.net/PfZwx/

Comment: @bfavaretto upvoted your comment, as I forgot to include my fiddle. I also saw the 4 seconds your post was up! :-P

Comment: It was actually 12 seconds! :)

Comment: Thank you! Hadn't even considered using a composite of multiple _ functions.

Comment: For newer versions of underscore, there is a function which does this directly: `mapObject`. This is equivalent to `mapValues` in lodash.

Answer (score 8):

Worth adding in here a solution that uses ES6 arrow functions, etc:

```
Object.keys(elements).map(f=>elements[f].temperature)
```

Note that this won't work on older javascript engines, but in node.js 0.12 with `--harmony` it works great, or with node.js 4.x and later as well.  I just tested this in Chrome 46 and it works fine.

It has the advantage of not needing any extra libraries such as underscore or lodash, but of course only works on new JS engines.

Comment: in a no ES6 notation: Object.keys(elements).map(function(f) {return elements[f].temperature})

Comment: But where is the fun in that? ;-)

Comment: This is a useful technique, but note this doesn’t return the object the questioner wanted, it just returns an array without the element names.

Answer (score 3):

on lodash (similar to underscore) , you can use `_.mapValues(elements,'temperature')`.
it's return `{steam: 100, water: 50, ice: 0}`

lodash ref : [_.mapValues](https://lodash.com/docs#mapValues)

by the way you can use `_.mapKeys` to build object hash in one line
`_.mapKeys(elements,'color') //{orange: Object, blue: Object, white: Object}`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need 3rd party libraries for easy stuff like this

```
// with a plain old for loop
const temps = {}
for (let key in data["elements"]) {
    dikt[key] = temps["elements"][key]["temperature"]
}
return temps

// with a reduce

Object.keys(data['elements']).reduce((acc, key) => acc[key] = data['elements'][key]['temperature'] , temps)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [JavaScript for-in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921789/how-to-loop-through-javascript-object-literal-with-objects-as-members) to iterate through the keys of the object:

```
var list = [];

// Iterate through each object key, and pick wanted the values.
for(var name in obj)
{
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(name) && name === "temperature")
    {
       list.push(obj[name]);
    }
}
```

The above is a simplified example, but you should be able to easily modify to encapsulate it in a more generic function. Also, you don't really need to use JQuery here - native JavaScript implementation will be faster.

The `obj.hasOwnProperty(name)` check is recommended by [JSLint](http://jslint.com/).

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions there is actually a built in function which does this.

If you give a string, instead of a function, to `mapObject`, it will interpret that as a property name and behave as a "`pluckObject`". Most functions are surprisingly liberal in what they accept.

```
> _.mapObject(elements,'temperature')
Object {steam: 100, water: 50, ice: 0}
```

If you want an explicit function for the purpose, you can look at how `_.pluck` is [implemented](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-34) and write your own analogous version:

```
_.mixin({
  pluckObject: function(obj, key) {
    return _.mapObject(obj, _.property(key));
  }
});
```

This is a bit redundant, but it makes your intentions clearer.