# How to Iterate through all object properties

Tags: javascript, object

I want Iterate through all object properites. I was trying to do this by using

```
for( var key in obj)
```

But that didnt give me all properties. For example, there is no key 'click'. But when i try to do

```
obj['click']
```

i got something.

I am trying to do this on IE7

Comment: What is this __something__ you're getting?

Comment: If you are iterating correctly, perhaps you are using the `hasOwnProperty`, like http://stackoverflow.com/a/921808/613130, so you are skipping properties defined in "parent" objects.

Answer (score 3):

The `for .. in` loop iterates over all `enumerable` properties, not over all properties.

So I would suspect either the `click` is not enumerable or you missed something.

Example on how to set a property which will not be available via the `for .. in` loop:

```
var obj = {};

Object.defineProperty(obj, "stealth", {
  enumerable: false,
  value: "you don't iterate over me"
});

// obj.stealth === "you don't iterate over me"

for (var i in obj) {
  // Loop will not enter here
}
```

You can test whether property is enumerable (i.e. will be accessible in a `for .. in` loop) using `Object.propertyIsEnumerable()` method:

```
obj.propertyIsEnumerable('stealth') === false
```

Comment: is there any possibility to get all properties?

Comment: @JohnSmith - yes, it's `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj);` but it's not supported by IE prior to version 9.

Answer (score 1):

For/in runs over all enumerable properties, including those inherited from ancestor prototypes. If you just want the ones for "your object", use `Object.keys()`:

```
Object.keys(yourobject).forEach(function(propertyName) {
  var value = yourobject[propertyName];
  console.log(propertyName + ":", value);
});
```