# How to get length from array with curly brackets

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm making an ajax call and the response I get is something like this:

```
   Object {
        Monday noon: Array[4], 
        Tuesday morning: Array[2], 
        Friday noon: Array[3], 
        Sunday: Array[1]
    }
```

I would like to do something like:

```
    response.length
```

But what i get back is `undefined`

Any idea how can i get the length inside of the Object array?

Another question is:
How could I get to the array of `Monday noon: Array[4]`? Any help or tutorial link will be appreciated.

Comment: An object is not an array.

Comment: That's not an array, that's an object literal.

Comment: Got it! - Quick question - could you guys help me on how to get to the array of `Monday noon: Array[4]` or could you point me to link that could help me with it :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want the number of keys in the object use:

```
var length = Object.keys(obj).length;
```

If you need a `Object.keys` polyfill:

```
if (!('keys' in Object.prototype)) {
  Object.keys = function (obj) {
    var arr = [], prop;
    if (util.toType(obj) === 'object') {
      for (prop in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
          arr.push(prop);
        }
      }
    }
    return arr;
  };
}
```

Comment: question - could you help me on how to get to the array of `Monday noon: Array[4]` or could you point me to link that could help me with it :/

Comment: @Louis, I can't believe you cancelled the answer. Tch. Post a new question with the structure of the object (not the output in the console) and someone can take a look.

Comment: yeah, i was going to do that, but every time i do that I start getting negative points because they say i asked already :/ - anyways, thx!

Comment: @Louis, I ask only because it's not clear whether `monday` is an object and `noon` is an array in that object. If it is you would do `obj.Monday.noon`.

Comment: the object looks just like this: 

`{
 "Monday noon": [
  {
   "photo": "/media/defaults/profile.png", 
   "meeting": "7:00am", 
  },
  {
   "photo": "/media/defaults/profile.png", 
   "meeting": "1:00pm", 
  }
 ], 
 "Tuesday morning": [
  {
   "photo": "/media/defaults/profile.png", 
   "meeting": "4:00pm", 
  }
 ]
}`

I would like to get to the meeting time... I wonder if that was possible. Sorry still new to this array/js stuff... :/

Comment: `obj['Monday noon']`. You can access object properties with dot notation and by providing the name in square brackets in quotes. Very necessary if you have a space in the property name.

Answer (score 3):

Objects don't have a `length` property. You can [loop through the properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921789/how-to-loop-through-javascript-object-literal-with-objects-as-members) and increment a counter:

```
var counter = 0;
for (var prop in obj) {
  if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
    counter++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, not unless you happen to set a `length` key in the object ;)

Comment: question - could you help me on how to get to the array of `Monday noon: Array[4]` or could you point me to link that could help me with it :/

Answer (score 0):

```
var len = 0;
for(var prop in response){
    if(response.hasOwnProperty(prop))
        len++;
}
```