# Unexpected result pushing objects into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, iteration

How to iterate over an array of literal objects in JavaScript?

I would like to do something like that:

```
grupo = []; // declare array

text = {}; // declare new object
text.a = "texta"; // declare property "a" of an object.
text.b = "textb";
grupo.push(text); // add object to array

text = {}; // declare new object
text.a = "textc"; // declare property
grupo.push(text); // add object with other property

// Iterate over
for (i=0; i<=grupo.length; i++) {
    console.dir(grupo[i].text.a);
}
```

Comment: negative, but no explain why... I hate that.

Comment: for (var i=0;i<grupo.length; i++)

Comment: is not the same question... maybe i not explained correctly, im need acess propertyes on object, when iterate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various errors in that code:

1. You're putting the **same** object in the array twice, not putting two objects in the array. After you push `text` into the array, you're just overwriting the `a` property on the same object and pushing it again. You haven't created a new object.
2. You haven't declared any of your variables (everywhere you've said "declare" in your comments, those are not declarations), so you're falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). Use `var` to declare variables.
3. A line comment should start with `//`, not `\\` (those cause a syntax error)
4. The `for` loop at the end should use `<`, not `<=`, for its termination condition. For the various ways to loop through arrays in JavaScript, [see this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-in-an-array-how-to-do-that-in-javascript).

Here's a cleaned-up version of that code:

```
var text, grupo, i; // Declare variables

text = {};          // Create an object and assign it to the variable
grupo = [];         // Create an array and assign it to the variable

text.a = "texta";   // Set the property `a` on the object
text.b = "textb";   // Set the property `b` on the object
grupo.push(text);   // Put that object onto the array
text = {};          // Create a second object
text.a = "textc";   // Set the property `a` on that new object
grupo.push(text);   // Put that object on the array

for (i=0;i<grupo.length;i++) {
//         ^-------------------- Note no =
    console.dir(grupo[i].text.a);
}
```

Comment: thx, i understand how it works now, your explanation is very usefull for me.

Comment: Do you now, why google console returns: TypeError: Cannot read property 'a' of undefined

Comment: that works:
`console.dir(grupo[i].a);`
Because javascript array use just numeric index. :)

Comment: @MarceloAymone: Sorry, I didn't notice that. The reason `grupo[i].text.a` didn't work is that `grupo[i]` **is** the object.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
for (var key in validation_messages) {
var obj = validation_messages[key];
   for (var prop in obj) {
      // important check that this is objects own property 
      // not from prototype prop inherited
      if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
        alert(prop + " = " + obj[prop]);
      }
   }
}
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/921808/1054926

Answer (score 0):

groupo[i] is already a text object so you there is an error there. Also, you don't want to look until your index is <= to the length.

Here is a quick look at what you may be looking for in your loop:

```
for (i=0;i<grupo.length;i++) {  
console.log(i,grupo[i].a);
```

}

However you will have additional problem when you discover that the value of "a" is not what you may be expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Here another possible "solution"

```
var text = {};  
var grupo = []; 

text.a = "texta";
text.b = "textb";
grupo.push(text);
text.a = "textc";
grupo.push(text);

for (var i=0;i < grupo.length;i++) {  
    var x = grupo[i];
    if (x && x.a){
        console.log(x.a);        
    } else {
        console.log(x);                
    }
}
```

Comment: portuguese version is not very efficient, but thx for the tip.