# How to read certain specified fields from text file in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using text file data for my script. I am loading the text file and getting the data from it. The text file contains data as below.

```
'DoctorA': {name: "Pharmaceuticals", title: "Switzerland, 120000 employees"},
'DoctorB': {name: "Consulting", title: "USA, 5500 employees"},
'DoctorC': {name: "Diagnostics", title: "USA, 42000 employees"},
'DoctorD': {name: "Fin Serv. & Wellness", title: "South Africa,  employees"},
```

I load and use something like this to read the data from that text file.

```
data.speakers=names_val[0];
```

I have not fully specified my script. My problem is I am getting the entire text file when I load into data.speakers. Is there anyway to read only that *title*: fields or only that *name*: field

Comment: Are you converting this string data into JSON objects?

Comment: Yes am converting into objects.is there anyway to read only that title key value?

Comment: You would do something like: `var title = data[ "DoctorA" ].title`

Comment: No use man can you suggest anyother way?

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading all the file as a JSON structure, you have to add a starting `{` and an ending `}`. Also you should put name and title between `"` (and notice sigle quote is not valid)

```
{
"DoctorA": {"name": "Pharmaceuticals", "title": "Switzerland, 120000 employees"},
"DoctorB": {"name": "Consulting", "title": "USA, 5500 employees"},
"DoctorC": {"name": "Diagnostics", "title": "USA, 42000 employees"},
"DoctorD": {"name": "Fin Serv. & Wellness", "title": "South Africa,  employees"}
}
```

Last "DoctorX" must not have a trailing comma, also.

Use http://jsonlint.com/ to check if your JSON is valid

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a valid JSON format obtained from your text file.

You can do this

```
var names = [];
var titles = [];
for (key in doctors) {
    var doctor = doctors[key];
    names.push(doctor.name);
    titles.push(doctor.title);
}
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/U9S8y/3/)

Comment: for further reading [Looping in Javascript Object Literal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921789/how-to-loop-through-javascript-object-literal-with-objects-as-members)