# Loop through PHP associative array in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have the following PHP associative array output as a response to jquery post request:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [user] => 25
    )
)
```

How can iterate through the above PHP associative array in javascript or jquery? Is this possible? or should I print the output of PHP in another way? I have access to the PHP as well

Comment: json_encode it.

Comment: You're going to have to post more code than that, for instance what does the javascript actually look like, how are you sending the array etc?

Comment: using json is the best option IMO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP just echo using `json_encode`:

```
$array = array(array('user' => 25));
echo json_encode($array); // [{"user":25}]
```

In Jquery:

```
var data = $.parseJSON(jsonString); // '[{"user":25}]'
console.log(data[0].user); // 25
```

Comment: how can i loop through all array values? this returns only the first pair...if i have multiple how can access all elements?

Comment: You can use for loop. `for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {     alert(data[i].user); }`

Comment: one last question. what about if `user` is different each time like the following json string: `[{"hey":25},{"mate":12}]`

Comment: You need to use another loop. `for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { for(key in data[i]){ console.log(data[i][key]); } }`

Comment: how can I do the same loop in jquery? currently i have `$.each(data, function(i, item) {
                  $.each(data[i], function(j, key) {
           alert(data[j][key]);
    });
             });`

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I use in a similar application:

PHP:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
if ( $_REQUEST["jsoncallback"] ) {
    $callback = htmlentities( $_REQUEST["jsoncallback"] );
}
$output = json_encode( $array );
if ( $callback ) {
    $output = $callback . "(" . $output . ")"; // I know the variables can be embedded in the strings, I don't care, I like it this way.
}
echo $output;
```

Javascript:

```
var getURL = "http://www.example.com/script.php?jsoncallback=?";
jQuery.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: getURL,
    success: function(data){
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( data );
        // now you can loop through the data object
    }
});
```

For the looping part, this question/answer might be helpful: [How to Loop through plain JavaScript object with objects as members?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921789/how-to-loop-through-javascript-object-literal-with-objects-as-members)