# Function parameter turns into Object's Name instead of its reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, string, pass-by-reference

this is my JSON structure:

```
var json = {
procedure: {
    id: "content",
    child: {

        154: {
        class: "sequence nest",
        text: "LED Ausgeben",
        id: 154
        }
    }
}    
};
```

For some reason prop in `for (var prop in scope.child){}` is only a string instead of the object scope.child.154 as you can see below at Watch Expressions.

[image: Debugger]

any ideas why? i tried specifying JSON objects with "154" but it doesn't matter. do their names have to contain characters aswell?

here is the fiddle: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/philx_x/cgojh6t1/14/) but you have to use the browsers console. to check it, press on the folder icon.

cheers!

Comment: That is because you *are* passing the property name, not the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the for loop slightly. You should have access to the object doing it this way.

```
for (var key in scope.child) {
  var obj = scope.child[key];
  ...
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cgojh6t1/21/)

Also check out [Stackover post where I got the idea from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921789/how-to-loop-through-javascript-object-literal-with-objects-as-members)

Comment: awesome, i changed your fiddle a little bit since i don't have to iterate over all properties and can pass the whole object in the $() function.
Here is the working Fiddle if you're intrested: http://jsfiddle.net/philx_x/cgojh6t1/