# Convert Array of Javascript Objects to single simple array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have not been able to figure out how to properly accomplish this.

I have a JS array of objects that looks like this:

```
[{"num":"09599","name":"KCC","id":null},{"num":"000027","name":"Johns","id":null}]
```

I would like to convert this into a simple, single JS array, without any of the keys, it should look like this:

```
[
  "09599",
  "KCC",
  "000027",
  "Johns" ]
```

The IDs can be dropped entirely. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You don't want the `id`s?

Comment: no, thanks for reminding me

Comment: @op it is polite to show what you have tried so far in order to accomplish it, and explain why your attempts did not work for you.

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921789/how-to-loop-through-javascript-object-literal-with-objects-as-members for a generic strategy that could be applied to this problem

Comment: @wolffer-east thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply iterate the original array, pick the interesting keys and accumulate them in another array, like this

```
var keys = ['num', 'name'],
    result = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) {
  // Get the current object to be processed
  var currentObject = data[i];
  for (var j = 0; j < keys.length; j += 1) {
    // Get the current key to be picked from the object
    var currentKey = keys[j];
    // Get the value corresponding to the key from the object and
    // push it to the array
    result.push(currentObject[currentKey]);
  }
}
console.log(result);
// [ '09599', 'KCC', '000027', 'Johns' ]
```

Here, `data` is the original array in the question. `keys` is an array of keys which you like to extract from the objects.

---

If you want to do this purely with functional programming technique, then you can use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), [`Array.prototype.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) and [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), like this

```
var keys = ['num', 'name'];

console.log(data.reduce(function (result, currentObject) {
  return result.concat(keys.map(function (currentKey) {
    return currentObject[currentKey];
  }));
}, []));
// [ '09599', 'KCC', '000027', 'Johns' ]
```

Comment: This is very specific. Wouldn't `Object.keys` make this solution far more generic.

Comment: @Mouser OP didn't want the `id` to be extracted.

Comment: I know, but a black list is better then a white list, with many keys?

Comment: @Mouser It is subjective. What if the original object had 100 keys and OP wanted to get only 2 keys?

Comment: @thefourtheye Thank you so much, it works perfectly.
Additionally thank you for taking the time to explain everything!

Comment: Thought of that too. Perhaps for future viewers and to be complete add another version with a blacklist.

Comment: @Mouser Hmmm, then we need to do lookup in the blacklist as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys()` and `.forEach()` method to iterate through your array of object, and use `.map()` to build your filtered array.

```
  var array = [{"num":"09599","name":"KCC","id":null},{"num":"000027","name":"Johns","id":null}];

  var filtered = array.map(function(elm){
    var tmp = [];
    //Loop over keys of object elm
    Object.keys(elm).forEach(function(value){
      //If key not equal to id
      value !== 'id'
      //Push element to temporary array
      ? tmp.push(elm[value])
      //otherwise, do nothing
      : false
    });
    //return our array
    return tmp;

  });

  //Flat our filtered array
  filtered = [].concat.apply([], filtered);

  console.log(filtered);
  //["09599", "KCC", "000027", "Johns"]
```

Comment: If we have to do it functional way, I have included a version in my answer. That would be better, I believe.

Comment: Yep, functional is the way to go :)

Answer (score 0):

How about using `map` :

```
var data =  [
              {"num":"09599","name":"KCC","id":null} 
              {"num":"000027","name":"Johns","id":null}
            ];

var result = data.map(function(obj) {
   return [
       obj.num,
       obj.name,
       obj.id
    ];
});
```