# Creating a function with properties

Tags: javascript, function, object, javascript-objects

Sorry, I don´t know the name of this.

I want to have a function and an object with properties in only one variable.

Here is how it works:

```
var obj = function() {
    return "foo";
};

obj.prop = "bar";

obj(); // => "foo"
obj.prop; // => "bar"
```

This works fine, but I would like to change the order of this:

```
var obj = { prop: "bar" };
obj = function() {
    return "foo";
};

obj(); // => "foo"
obj.prop; // => undefined
```

Is there a way to do this?

I want do do this because I have a lot of properties to add to the object:

```
var obj = function() {
    return "foo";
};

obj.prop1 = "bar1";
obj.prop2 = "bar2";
obj.prop3 = "bar3";
obj.prop4 = "bar4";
obj.prop5 = "bar5";
obj.prop6 = "bar6";
obj.prop7 = "bar7";
//...
```

Comment: Technically, you could, but it would be much more code that what you have here. To do this simply, I agree with @Grundy. You can't.

Comment: @aaronfrost What do you mean, defining the properties first (before creating the function) and then copying them to the function object later?

Comment: @Martin see my updated answer (in answer to your updated question).

Comment: @torazaburo, like in the answers below. You can do it. But, it takes code to do it.

Comment: @torazaburo you´re right, I should have done this, but like you said in another comment, this doesn´t matter because I only want to assign about 20 properties.

Comment: @torazaburo y so agressive? We are just trying to help.

Comment: @torazaburo if you refuse to see it, then theres not much to say.

Comment: Hey, don´t battle.  :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't possible because when you do:

```
obj = function() {
    return "foo";
};
```

...you're assigning the variable `obj` to the new function, so it no longer points to the original object you created (`{ prop: "bar" }`) at all.

So if you want to add properties to a function object, you must always create the function first, then add properties.

As an alternative, you could do something like this:

```
var props = {
    prop1: "bar1",
    prop2: "bar2"
};

var obj = function() {
    return "foo";
};

for (var key in props) {
    obj[key] = props[key];  
}
```

Or if you happen to have jQuery available (and don't have `Object.assign` available):

```
jQuery.extend(obj, props);
```

(Of course there are shims available for `Object.assign`, which would allow @Pointy's answer to work in older browsers.)

Comment: In your loop, you should check that `props.hasOwnProperty(key)` http://stackoverflow.com/a/921808/1913729

Comment: Yes, this would work with little code.  I will accept this answer, If there are no better solutions (performance).

Comment: @blex I don't think that's necessary in this case...the OP says nothing to indicate that the `props` object would be an instance of some prototype (i.e. that it would have inherited enumerable properties).

Comment: @Martin Thanks...I could be wrong, but I don't see how you could make it perform better than this, unless the native implementation of `Object.assign` (available in newer browsers) has some internal performance optimization...in any case I wouldn't worry about it - better to be concerned about performance differences that are actually significant than little things like looping over a few dozen properties...

Answer (score 5):

If you want to do this with one statement, ES2015 (and some libraries) let you do:

```
var obj = Object.assign(
  function() { /* ... */ },
  { "hello": "world" }
);
```

Which will give you `obj` as a function with the property "hello". Note that this is really just the same thing as the separate assignment, but it's all wrapped up as one overall expression, which is nice because it means you can do something like

```
return Object.assign(function() { /* whatever */ }, {
  prop: whatever,
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Yes, this would work, but I need a solution which also works in IE8

Comment: I agree with @torazaburo...either his answer or mine should serve you equally well. The performance differences are insignificant. Avoid premature optimization.

Comment: @MattBrowne Right. Wasn't my answer but whatever.

Answer (score 0):

I also agree with Grundy, but you could do something like that:

```
var x = function(){
var obj = {};
  return {
    objToReturn: obj,
    objFunction: function(){return 'foo';},
    addItemsToObject: function (key, value) {
      obj[decodeURIComponent(key)] = value;
    }
   }
};
```

**I honestly don't know if that's what you really want**, but in that case you can execute the "x" function and after you can access the
"objFunction", the "objToReturn" or the "addItemsToObject" function.

So it will be something like that:

```
var y = x();

for (propertie in yourProperties){      
  y.addItemsToObject
    (propertie, yourProperties[decodeURIComponent(propertie)]);
}
```

And then:

```
y.objFunction();

'foo'
```

Hope that helps.