# Loop through JavaScript Object but keep key with value

Tags: html, reactjs, object-literal

```
var data = {
  2016-09-24: {
    0: {amount: 200, id: 2},
    1: {...}
  },
  2016-09-25: {
    0: {amount: 500, id: 8},
    1: {...}
  }
}
```

I want to represent the above data in a view like:

"**" would be a div with a `card` class:

```
*****************************************
* <h2>2016-09-24</h2>                   *
*                                       *
* <li>amount: 200</li>                  *
* <li>amount: 40</li>                   *
*                                       *
*****************************************

*****************************************
* <h2>2016-09-25</h2>                   *
*                                       *
* <li>amount: 500</li>                  *
* <li>amount: 90</li>                   *
*                                       *
*****************************************
```

I have yet to reach the layout but stuck at the loop. Im using React es6:

```
dailySales(){
  Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
    var dates = key;
    var val = data[key];

    let sales = val.map(function(s, i) {
      //console.log(s.amount);
    });
  });
}
```

The above commented out `console.log` would return all `amount`. How to segment each value with the date (key)? This question is similar [to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921789/how-to-loop-through-javascript-object-literal-with-objects-as-members).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the wise words of Leonardo DiCaprio in "Inception", "we need to go deeper"

You're super close and on the right track. You need to loop over the nested objects again and you'll get what you're looking for:

```js
Object.keys( data ).map( function( date, i ) {

    // here you have the date
    return (
        <div key={ i }>
            <h1>{ date }</h1>
            { Object.keys( data[ date ] ).map( function( item, j ) {
                // and here you have the item by its key
                var rowItem = data[date][item];
                return (
                    <p key={ rowItem.id }>Amount: { rowItem.amount }</p>
                );
            })}
        </div>
    );

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/64s0yvvz/1/

Comment: React is complaining and the amount is not showing: `Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop`

Comment: @Sylar Did you look at the fiddle I posted? It's working as intended.

Comment: Ok. Yes I have seen your typo! You have `{ item.amount }` when it should have been `{ rowItem.amount }`.

Comment: nice catch. go team.