# javascript :how to make an addition of value of specific key of different object

Tags: javascript, object, operation

take an object, containing several objects. Those objects can have a specific key called `number`, whose value is a number. 
How can I addition all the "number" value of the objects that have this key `number`...

```
var myObject = {
    item1 = {
        name: "someName",
        color: "someColor2", 
        number: intValue
     },
     item2 = {
        name: "someName2",
        color: "someColor2"
     },
     item3 = {
        name: "someName3",
        color: "someColor3", 
        number: intValue
     },
     item4 = {
        name: "someName4",
        color: "someColor4" 
     },
};
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Iterate through the objects and access their `number` property and sum them.

Comment: Just loop over each object, check if it has a `number` property, and if so, add it to a sum. Google is your friend

Comment: Please try and google the question first. I googled "iterate through javascript object containing other objects" and got [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921789/how-to-loop-through-plain-javascript-object-with-objects-as-members) as the first result

Comment: The code that you're showing is not valid JavaScript. Please [edit] your answer to provide the code you're actually working with.

Comment: Your object should probably be an array, not an object. Any time you have variables or properties with numeric suffixes, you should usually use an array instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect use-case for `Array.reduce`! However, since your input is an *object* instead of an array, we'll need to use `Object.keys` to obtain the list of item names, which list will then drive the reducer loop.

```
// your object def wasn't valid, so I made my own
var myObject = {
    item1: { name: 'item one',   color: 'red',    number: 1 },
    item2: { name: 'item two',   color: 'orange', number: 2 },
    item3: { name: 'item three', color: 'yellow', number: 3 },
    item4: { name: 'item four',  color: 'green',  number: 4 },
    item5: { name: 'item five',  color: 'blue',   number: 5 },
    item6: { name: 'item six',   color: 'indigo', number: 6 },
    item7: { name: 'item seven', color: 'violet', number: 7 }
};

var total = Object.keys(myObject) //=> ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', ...]
.reduce(function(sum, itemName) {
    return sum += myObject[itemName].number;
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var sum = 0;

for (var prop in myObject)
{
   sum += myObject[prop].number || 0;
}
```

that may be a beginning of **something**....

Comment: Hello and thank you for the answer. I tried what you proposed but could not succeed. I also tried to do if (item.hasOwnProperty('number')) but sum stays to 0.