# Take a specif field from an Array of Object and remove the duplicated ones

Tags: javascript, arrays, unique

suppose with we have an array of objects like this:
array = [{side:1, value:2}, {side:1, value:3}, {side:2, value:4}, {side:2, value: 4}, {side:3, value:3}] I want to create an array which contains only the side attibute without duplications like this:
sideArray = [1,2,3]. These are the values of the side. How to do this?

Comment: I think that will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921789/how-to-loop-through-plain-javascript-object-with-objects-as-members :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map()` method to return array with side values and then `Set` and spread syntax to remove duplicates.

```js
var array = [{side:1, value:2}, {side:1, value:3}, {side:2, value:4}, {side:2, value: 4}, {side:3, value:3}]

var result = [...new Set(array.map(e => e.side))];
console.log(result)
```