# How to iterate through objects inside objects inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have pulled down from firebase and been given a payload of an array with 3 objects inside which themselves contain objects.

Consider the following screenshot:

[image]

This is what happens when i console.log my months array.

how do i iterate through this to log out any information i want from inside the object?

for example i want whats inside month and inside p1, p2.

i have tried to do

`this.state.months.map()` and then to log `month.month` but that returns undefined.

any ideas?

Comment: Use nested loops

Comment: What are these "-Kuog..." things?

Comment: I think those are keys generated by the server. @lilezek

Comment: Maybe you should post the actual json instead of some ambiguous screenshot?

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript plus https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921789/how-to-loop-through-plain-javascript-object-with-objects-as-members?rq=1

Comment: You can't access `month.month` from months.map() because that key generated.

Comment: Can you include the code as text at Question, instead of an image? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

how about using `for-in` loops inside the `for` loop against the array?

```
for (var i = 0, l = this.state.months.length; i < l; i++) {
  var obj = this.state.months[i];
  for (var key in obj) {
    //check if obj owns the property and not some prototype
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      console.log(obj[key].p1); //what do we do with p1?
      console.log(obj[key].p2); //what do we do with p2?
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: for some reason this prints out the same value in every iteration? i.e. p1.score and p1.name is printed out in every loop instead of it changing every time as it iterates. if that makes any sense

Comment: how about posting a sample json?

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way

```
jList = this.state.months
jList.map(jList=>(jList.month+ ", "+ jList.p1 + ", " + jList.p2))
```

**OUTPUT-** will be an array

```
["some-Monthname, p1-someval, p2-someval", ... ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just based on the screenshot you provided, you have an array of objects that contain the month object. You can loop through that array and then map them into an array of just the months and their information. That will make dealing with the months more manageable.

```
var months = this.state.months.forEach( function( item ) {
    return { month: item.month, p1: item.p1, p2: item.p2 };
});
```

Then you access the month and its data like so.

```
console.log( 'Month is ', months[0].month, '. p1 object data is ', months[0].p1 '. and p2 object data is ', months[0].p2);
```