# Converting a for loop to forEach not working

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2017

I have an object with some propreties:

```
const carOptions = {
  mazda: 25000,  
  tesla: 85000,
  bmw: 100000
}
```

I would like to convert a `for` loop …

```
for (let i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
  if (cars[i].checked) {
    return carOptions[cars[i].id]
  }
}
…
```

… To `.forEach` but this code isn't working:

```
cars.forEach(function(cars)) {
  if (cars.checked) {
    return carOptions[cars.id]
  }
}
…
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `forEach` doesn't work on objects. You could use `Object.keys(carOptions)` or `Option.values(carOptions)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921789/how-to-loop-through-a-plain-javascript-object-with-the-objects-as-members

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to loop through a plain JavaScript object with the objects as members?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921789/how-to-loop-through-a-plain-javascript-object-with-the-objects-as-members)

Comment: You ask about `cars` but your post starts with `carOptions`, and that's not an array.

Comment: @Pointy That's not the array he's looping over, it's used inside the loop in `carOptions[cars[i].id]`

Comment: @Barmar yes I've pieced it together, but `cars` should have been in the question obviously.

Comment: @LucaFabbri That doesn't solve the problem. His problem is with how to return the result when he uses `forEach`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're returning from the callback function, not the containing function.

You should set a variable in the `forEach()` callback, and then return that outside the loop.

```
var checkedOption;
cars.forEach(car => {
    if (car.checked) {
        checkedOption = carOptions[car.id];
    }
});
return checkedOption;
```

Note that this is not as efficient as the `for` loop. The loop will stop and return from the function as soon as it finds a match. But there's no way to stop `forEach()` in the middle, it will keep testing the remaining cars. And if there are multiple checked cars, `checkedOption` will be set to the options corresponding to the last one, not the first.

You could instead use `.find()`:

```
var checkedCar = cars.find(car => car.checked);
if (checkedCar) {
    return carOptions[checkedCar.id];
}
```

Comment: Are you recommending that I stick with a `for` loop or use `.find()`?

Comment: If you want the functional approach, use `.find()`.

Comment: It's just a matter of style. Some people like functions, some like statements.