# How to convert firebase object to array?

Tags: javascript, axios

I am using firebase with axios. 
I need to convert this Object:

```
{r1: "Room 1", r2: "Room 2", r3: "Room 3"}
```

Into an Array:

```
rooms = [
    { id: 'r1', name: 'Room 1'},
    { id: 'r2', name: 'Room 2'},
    { id: 'r3', name: 'Room 3'},
];
```

Currenltly, I cam calling from firebase with axious like this:

```
axios.get('firebaseURL').then(response => {console.log(response.data)});
```

Comment: You're going to have to write some code to convert from one format to another.  The REST API isn't going to do this for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to loop through a plain JavaScript object with the objects as members?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921789/how-to-loop-through-a-plain-javascript-object-with-the-objects-as-members)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5737192/6749142).

```
const array = [];

Object.keys(yourObject).forEach((key) => {
  array.push({[key]: object1[key]});
});
```

Comment: I managed to convert it to an array. But when i console log, there is a slight difference and my application is not receiving the data.

I am getting: 
`[] `
`0: {id: "r1", name: "Room 1"}`
`2: {id: "r2", name" "Room 2"}`
`3: {id: "r3", name" "Room 3"}`

but what I should be getting is: 
`(3) [{...}, {...}, {...}]`
`0: {id: "r1", name: "Room 1"}`
`2: {id: "r2", name" "Room 2"}`
`3: {id: "r3", name" "Room 3"}`

The difference is in the first row of code. Is that the reason why my application is not receiving the data?

Comment: hello, I've managed to pass my data over already! thank you for your help :)

Comment: Nice that you solved it by yourself! Making progress :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Object.keys(rooms)` with `map()` - The `Object.keys` returns an array with all the object keys, and the `map` function accepts each key, and will return whatever you make of that key into a new array.
So in the snippet below `Object.keys(rooms)` is equal to `[ 'r1', 'r2', 'r3' ]` and from that it is easy to construct your desired array.

```js
const rooms = {r1: "Room 1", r2: "Room 2", r3: "Room 3"};

const arrayResult = Object.keys(rooms).map(room => {
    return {id: room, name: rooms[room]} 
});
```

Comment: managed to convert it to an array. But when i console log, there is a slight difference and my application is not receiving the data. I am getting: [] 0: {id: "r1", name: "Room 1"} 2: {id: "r2", name" "Room 2"} 3: {id: "r3", name" "Room 3"} but what I should be getting is: (3) [{...}, {...}, {...}] 0: {id: "r1", name: "Room 1"} 2: {id: "r2", name" "Room 2"} 3: {id: "r3", name" "Room 3"} The difference is in the first row of code. Is that the reason why my application is not receiving the data? Im trying to convert the firebase object to an array via axios.

Comment: hello, I've managed to pass my data over already! thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

you can try this using this package https://github.com/just1and0/object-to-array-convert

```
import { O2A } from 'object-to-array-convert';

const rooms = {r1: "Room 1", r2: "Room 2", r3: "Room 3"};

const value = O2A(rooms);

return value
```